# Modeling a tree-like structure in db with EF

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity-framework, relational-database

I have a huge performance problem with EF shoveling my data out of the database.

Let's say I have a class hierarchy like this (imagine these are all EF generated):

```
public partial class Container {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   IEnumerable<Box> Boxes {get;set;}}

public partial class Box {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   IEnumerable<Part> Parts {get;set;}

   // Navigational property
   public virtual Container Container { get; set; }
}

public partial class Part{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   IEnumerable<Attachment> FrontAttachments {get;set;}
   IEnumerable<Attachment> BackAttachments {get;set;}}

public partial class Attachment{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   String Name;}
```

Now, since I need to seralized these things, and EF doesn't play nicely with WCF or ASP.NET MVC (because of loop references/navigation properties) - I created a duplicated set of objects, and called them: `ContainerDTO`, `BoxDTO`, `PartDTO`, `AttachmentDTO`.

To easily create DTO's I added a `DTO` property to each entity. E.g. on container it would look like this:

```
public partial class Container {
    public DTO get{
        return new ContainerDTO {
            Boxes = this.Boxes.Select(b=>b.DTO); //since Box also has DTO property
        }
    };
}
```

However, now when I do a query like:

```
 var db = context; //get context
 var containers = db.Container.ToList().Select(c=>c.DTO);
```

this actually generates thousands of queries (one for each container!).

What's worse, even if I do a complete query in LINQ. E.g.:

```
 var q = from container in db.Container
         select new BoxDTO{
             Parts = from part in container.Parts
                     select new PartDTO
                     {
                        ...
             }
          }
```

It still takes a long time (upwards of 10s for around 14K Boxes) just to convert results into C# equivalent DTOs.

Now, I rarely need to modify the data - mostly read it.
Has anyone ever had experience with such deeply nested, interrelated hierarchies? Would a document oriented database (e.g. mongodb) enable me to speed it up?

Any tips welcome.

Comment: Can't you expand tree nodes on demand? I can't imagine you have a page showing 14k boxes all at once. The "complete" query approach should potentially perform well. If materializing and serializing the objects is the bottleneck you may have to resort to other means, like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).

Comment: Not necessarily "showing" on a page, but some of our algorithms require all the data in "container". So instead of passing the reference to the database context, I would like to just load the whole thing into memory and pass that in instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider reading the answer to this post: [IEnumerable vs List - What to Use? How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work). It appears that you are forcing implementation with ToList() where this can be deferred with the use of an IEnumerable.