# Difference between IEnumeration<T> instead and List<T>?

Tags: c#

I am confused. Can anybody help me to understand Difference between `IEnumeration<T>` instead and `List<T>`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work follow this link...

Answer (score 2):

You mean `IEnumerable<T>`. It's the base interface of all collection types like arrays or generic `List<T>`.

You can for example create a `List<int>`:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>(){ 1,2,3 };
```

But since it implements `IEnumerable<T>` you could also declare it in this way:

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = new List<int>(){ 1,2,3 };
```

This has the advantage that you cannot modify `ints` since `Remove` comes from `ICollection<T>`.