# Why a lot of Linq methods return IEnumerable instead of a more specific type?

Tags: c#, linq

The title pretty much sums up the question. I don't have any problems with it, I'm just curious about reasons behind that design choice.

Comment: Because all LINQ methods accept `IEnumerable<T>` and it's good practise to make your methods as reusable as possible. Also, many methods use deferred execution, so they actually return no collection but a "query" you can chain with other methods. [IEnumerable vs List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work)

Comment: The cause are Extension methods on Enumerable and a fluent api design

Comment: It is also a good idea to work against the minimum public interface you need to. Most actions only need to work on `IEnumerable<T>` and will only return such, so it makes sense. There is no need to return a `List<T>` when all you want to do is iterate it.

Comment: To sum up the previous comments "The interface-segregation principle (ISP) states that no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle

Answer (score 1):

My Guess? Simplicity and compatibility for different providers.

Contrary to some other answers this has nothing to do with deferred execution - which is an important concept but irrelevant to the issue.  For example I could make the following completely valid method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> NotBuffered<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input) 
{
    return (IEnumerable<T>)input.ToList();  //not deferred
}
```

Alternatively I could expose a `WhereEnumerable` that works just like a `IEnumerable` but has the following properties:

```
WhereEnumerable data = source.Where(x=> x.Name == "Cheese"); //still deferred
print(data.First());
print(data.skipped); //Number of items that failed the test.
print(data.returned); //Number of items that passed the test.
```

And this could conceivably be useful - as demonstrated - and easy to implement in the basic *LinqToObjects* implementation.  However it might be considerably harder to impossible to implement the same functionality in the *LinqToSQL* or *LinqToMongo* or *LinqToOpenCL* drivers.  This would risk making code less portable between implementations, and increase the implementors complexity.

*For example MongoDB runs the query on the server (in a specialized query language) and does not make these stats available to the user.  Furthermore with concepts such as indexes, these concepts could be meaningless e.g. `users.Where(user => user.ID = "{ID"}).First()` on a index might 'skip' 0 records before finding the result, even if it's at position 100,412 in the Index or 40,231 on the disk or on index node 431.  That's a 'simple' problem...*

Lastly, you can always write your own LINQ methods to return your own custom types with this functionality if you wish or through overloads that output a 'stats' object and similar.  For a hypothetical example of the latter:

```
var stats = new WhereStats();
WhereEnumerable data = source.Where(x=> x.Name == "Cheese", stats);
print(data.First());
print(stats.skipped); //Number of items that failed the test.
print(stats.returned); //Number of items that passed the test.
```

Edit:  Example of a typed where (Proof of Concept Only):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TypedWhereExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000);
            var typedWhere1 = data.TypedWhere(x => x % 2 == 0);
            var typedWhere2 = typedWhere1.TypedWhere(x => x % 3 == 0);
            var result = typedWhere2.Take(10).ToList();  //Works like usual Linq

            //But returns additional data
            Console.WriteLine("Result: " + string.Join(",", result));
            Console.WriteLine("Typed Where 1 Skipped: " + typedWhere1.Skipped);
            Console.WriteLine("Typed Where 1 Returned: " + typedWhere1.Returned);
            Console.WriteLine("Typed Where 2 Skipped: " + typedWhere2.Skipped);
            Console.WriteLine("Typed Where 2 Returned: " + typedWhere2.Returned);
            Console.ReadLine();

            //Result: 0,6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54
            //Typed Where 1 Skipped: 27
            //Typed Where 1 Returned: 28
            //Typed Where 2 Skipped: 18
            //Typed Where 2 Returned: 10
        }
    }

    public static class MyLINQ
    {
        public static TypedWhereEnumerable<T> TypedWhere<T>
            (this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter)
        {
            return new TypedWhereEnumerable<T>(source, filter);
        }
    }

    public class TypedWhereEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        IEnumerable<T> source;
        Func<T, bool> filter;

        public int Skipped { get; private set; }
        public int Returned { get; private set; }

        public TypedWhereEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter)
        {
            this.source = source;
            this.filter = filter;
        }

        IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (var o in source)
                if (filter(o)) { Returned++; yield return o; }
                else Skipped++;
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (var o in source)
                if (filter(o)) { Returned++; yield return o; }
                else Skipped++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with your observation that this has nothing to do with deferred execution (see my answer), but I don't find your answer satisfying. The first example would be naturally implemented in Linq to objects using the .Aggregate function, so it doesn't need extra types. And there are plenty of methods that are not portable across implementations as it is, so that argument doesn't convince me either. I'm not going to downvote your answer though, because of the importent point that this has nothing to do with deferred execution.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten I agree that my answer may not be correct or complete, which is why I prefaced it with 'My Guess'.  I can debate some of your points, but that'd be a discussion.  Unless we can get the opinion of the design team this may be hard question to definitively answer.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1):

Just to make sure I understand your question correctly, I'll use an example:

Take this method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
```

I assume your question is: why does it return `IEnumerable<TSource>` and not, for example, an `Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>` ?

Note that the type above is the actual runtime type of the object returned, but the method simply declares it to be `IEnumerable<TSource>`.

The answer is that there would be virtually no benefit in doing otherwise, but there would be a non-zero cost. When the cost is higher than the benefit, don't do it.

Why is there no benefit?

First of all, because there would be many `WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>` objects around, that are still statically typed as `IEnumerable<TSource>`. As a result, method overloading would not work, and just as today, the Where method would have to try to cast its input to a `WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>` if it want to optimize the `.Where(...).Where(...)` sequence. There are several reasons why this is the case, one of them being this pattern:

```
IEnumerable<whatever> q = source;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
{
    q = q.Where(item => item.Name.Contains(searchText));
}

if (startDate.HasValue)
{
    // What is the runtime type of q? And what is its compiletime type?
    q = q.Where(item => item.Date > startDate.Value);
}
```

The non-zero cost is composed of maintenance and documentation cost (you make it more difficult to change your implementation if you expose it, and you have to document it), and increased complexity for the user.

Answer (score -1):

`IEnumerable`'s only yield a result upon enumeration. Say you have a query such as:

```
someEnumerable
    .Select(a=>new b(a))
    .Filter(b=>b.someProp > 10)
    .Select(b=>new c(b));
```

If the return value of the LINQ steps where something with eagerly evaluated contents such as a `List<T>` then each step would have to fully evaluate in order to pass into the next. With large inputs, this could mean a noticeable wait/lag while performing that step.

LINQ queries return a lazily evaluated `IEnumerable<T>`. The query is performed upon enumeration. Even if your source `IEnumerable<T>` had millions of records the above query would be instantaneous.

Edit: Think of LINQ queries as *creating a pipeline for your result* rather than *imperatively creating the result*. Enumeration is essentially opening the resulting pipeline and seeing what comes out.

Additionally, IEnumerables are the most upcasted form of a sequence in .NET e.g.

```
IList<T> :> ICollection<T> :> IEnumerable<T>
```

This gives you the most flexible interface available.

Comment: Types and deferred execution are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: I don't think it is always true that an `ICollection<T>` would _necessarily_ have to execute eagerly. But more importantly, what would be wrong with `interface IFilteredEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T> { }` to help in method overload selection? (There is something wrong BTW, see my answer.)

Comment: Reworded to reflect that.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is absolutely no reason why a hypothetical overload such as `IList<TResult> Select<TSource,TResult>(this IList<TSource> source, Function<TSource, TResult>)` would _have_ _to_ execute eagerly.

Comment: Again, you're right. But where in my answer did I use `IList<T>`? I specifically changed to an implementation, `List<T>`, to avoid the possible confusing scenario of someone implementing a lazily evaluated implementation of `IList<T>`.