# groupby count and percentage

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Is there a simple way to show a percentage of the total within a Linq `GroupBy`?

I currently have:

```
private static object GetPageUsers(IEnumerable<Pagehit> getPageLog)
{
    return getPageLog
          .GroupBy(g => g.UserID)
          .Select(x => new { User = GetUserFName(x.Key.ToString()),
                             NumberOfHits = x.Count(),
                             percentage = x.Count() / total
          })
          .OrderByDescending(o => o.NumberOfHits);
}
```

In this line `percentage = x.Count() / total` how do I get the total?

Comment: Can you tell us what your getPageLog contains? It will be better if you rephrase your question. It is not understandable.

Comment: Have you tried `percentage = x.Count() / getPageLog.Count()` *100 + "%"

Comment: Serv, thats exactly what I was looking for. Clearly not had enough coffee today! Thank you

Comment: Just wanted to test it myself before answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getPageLog is an IEnumerable, so it has no Count property. But it should have a `Count()` extension method.

You could get it using:

```
private static object GetPageUsers(IEnumerable<Pagehit> getPageLog)
{
    return getPageLog
          .GroupBy(g => g.UserID)
          .Select(x => new { User = GetUserFName(x.Key.ToString()),
                             NumberOfHits = x.Count(),
                             percentage = (100 * x.Count()) / getPageLog.Count() + "%"
          })
          .OrderByDescending(o => o.NumberOfHits);
}
```

Comment: Is getPageLog better as a `List<>`?

Comment: That depends on what you are doing. Using a List you are forcing the compiler to execute right away. Using an IEnumerable interface the execution is delayed until it is needed. There are far better explanations than mine around. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work