# IEnumreable and IQueryable

Tags: c#, ienumerable, iqueryable

Proper difference of `IEnumreable` and `IQueryable` .

Why this two interface used and when used?

Whats the benefit used over list?

What other methods consist in `IEnumreable` and `IQueryable`?

In what scenario we have to use `IEnumreable` and `IQueryable`?

Comment: IQueryable hasnt run the query yet.

The difference between list and ienumerable : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erickt/archive/2006/10/23/iqueryable-t-vs-ienumerable-t.aspx

Comment: Hi, this is not a interview question and answer site. You should try google or read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When querying a database, I prefer using a `IQueryable` because the request is sent when data are needed. I mean this

```
   var users = (from user in db.Users select user ).AsQueryable();
   //it doesn't load data yet until you write users.ToList(); or users.Count();
```