# Understanding AsEnumerable in Linq to Objects

Tags: c#, asenumerable

Written on msdn:

> Returns the input typed as `IEnumerable<T>`.

I do not understand.
Help me to understand  this method.

Comment: Jon Skeet did an excellent series on Linq to Objects. Here's [Part 36 - AsEnumerable](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/14/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-36-asenumerable.aspx)

Comment: Explains it perfectly: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work)

Comment: @Jodrell Apologies, I've managed to wipe your close vote by agreeing and then changing my mind; that wasn't my intention.

Comment: @Rawling, it appears I can't reinstate my vote :-S. No matter.

Comment: Here is a simple (maybe not so typical) example: `List<int> li = XXX; var reversedWithLinq = li.AsEnumerable().Reverse();`. The meaning of `AsEnumerable` is to "hide" other overloads defined by the actual type or interfaces other than `IEnumerable<>` to be sure the overload used is the one from the extension of `IEnumerable<>`. If you remove the `.AsEnumerable()` from my example, it won't compile since the other method returns `void`.

Answer (score 1):

There are three implementations of `AsEnumerable`.

**[`DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

Extends a `DataTable` to give it an `IEnumerable` interface so you can use Linq against the `DataTable`.

**[`Enumerable.AsEnumerable<TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`ParallelEnumerable.AsEnumerable<TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd413587%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

> The `AsEnumerable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` method has no effect
>   other than to change the compile-time type of source from a type that
>   implements `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` itself.
>
> `AsEnumerable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` can be used to choose
>   between query implementations when a sequence implements
>   `IEnumerable<T>` but also has a different set of public query methods
>   available. For example, given a generic class `Table` that implements
>   `IEnumerable<T>` and has its own methods such as `Where`, `Select`, and
>   `SelectMany`, a call to `Where` would invoke the public `Where` method of
>   `Table`. A `Table` type that represents a database table could have a
>   `Where` method that takes the predicate argument as an expression tree
>   and converts the tree to SQL for remote execution. If remote execution
>   is not desired, for example because the predicate invokes a local
>   method, the `AsEnumerable<TSource>` method can be used to hide the
>   custom methods and instead make the standard query operators
>   available.

**In other words.**

If I have an

```
IQueryable<X> sequence = ...;
```

from a Linq Provider, like Entity Framework, and I do,

```
sequence.Where(x => SomeUnusualPredicate(x));
```

that query will be composed on and run on the server. This will fail at runtime because Entity Framework doesn't know how to convert `SomeUnusualPredicate` into SQL.

If I want that to run the statement with Linq to Objects instead,  I do,

```
sequence.AsEnumerable().Where(x => SomeUnusualPredicate(x));
```

now the server will return all the data and the `Enumerable.Where` from Linq to Objects will be used instead of the Query Provider's implementation.

It won't matter that Entity Framework doesn't know how to interpret `SomeUnusualPredicate`,  my function will be used directly. (However, this may be an inefficient approach since all rows will be returned from the server.)