# Remove items from an IList<Log> where log.id exists in IList<short>

Tags: c#, linq

Hi i am new to linq kindly pardon my bad keywords.

```
 IList<Log> pendingLogs = rep.GetAllPending();
 IList<Short> pendingMessageInQueue = PendingCommandModel.GetPendingMessagesIds();
```

I have two lists.
I want to remove items from `pendingLogs` where item.Id exists in `pendingMessageInQueue`.
I could also have used `IEnumerable` if that is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: If it's actually a `List<Log>` you can use `List.RemoveAll` which does not require to create a new temporary list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new list with all items that you want to keep, you can use `!Contains`:

```
pendingLogs = pendingLogs 
    .Where(pl => !pendingMessageInQueue.Contains(pl.id))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Can you suggest me when to use Ilist or IEnumerable ??

Comment: @ShankerPaudel: `IEnumerable<T>` is the interface `List<T>` is an implementation. Use the appropriate type, if you want that the user of the collection cannot modify it easily make it `IEnumerable` since it doesn't support `Add` or `Remove` methods. If you want that the collection can be (or must be) changed afterwards use a `List`. I tend to use `IEnumerable<T>` to encapsulate it if the collection is filled completely. **Edit** Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work (LINQ only answers)

Comment: Also, if you want that the user of the collection cannot modify it, you can use the `AsReadOnly()` method of the `List<>` class so the `IEnumerable<T>` can't be cast back to `List<>` and be modified.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your original list [instead of creating a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23800237/142637), you can use a simple join to get the items you want to delete:

```
 foreach(var log in pendingMessageInQueue.Join(pendingLogs, 
                                               (id) => id,
                                               (log) => log.Id,
                                               (id, log) => log))
{
    pendingLogs.Remove(log);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this works? You're removing items from the list in a `foreach` which should raise an "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute"-exception.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, I'm sure. It works because `pendingLogs` is the *inner* part of the join, which will be converted into a `LookUp<,>` inside the `Join` method. Thus `pendingLogs` itself will be enumerated while `Remove` is called. But it would fail when `pendingLogs` where the *outer* part of the join.

Comment: You're right. However, i find it difficult to remember whether it is allowed or not. That's why i prefer a different approach in this case, although the `Join` can be more efficient..

Comment: Well, both ways have pros and cons.