# So the invention of lists made IEnumerable classes useless and waste of time?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

So with the introduction of lists we can easily do, what we used to do with IEnumerable classes. So now IEnumerable classes mostly used only to understand how internally the lists work. Am i right?

Comment: To my understanding, `IEnumerable` can be seen as an abstraction of `List`; I don't understand the perspective of seeing `IEnumerable` as a precursor of `List`, however.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. `IEnumerable` is an interface, `List` is a class. Go read [IEnumerable vs List - What to Use? How do they work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work).

Comment: The invention of the swimming pool has not made the garden hose useless and a waste of time. They serve different purposes.

Answer (score 3):

No. While a list is enumerable, the reverse is not quite true.

[`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as an interface states that you can *iterate over a series of elements*, whereas [`IList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states that *the element's order is preserved and you can randomly access them [in an efficient fashion – in .NET]*. Although both of these revolve around a collection-ish data structure, the promises the interfaces make are different. That said, many types offer both and therefore implement both interfaces (`List<T>`, `T[]`, ...).

Think of a data reader or a function computing a series of values (Fibonacci, prime numbers, ...), sets or trees for instance. None of there are lists, yet you can iterate over them using a method that takes an `IEnumerable` rather than and `IList` as a parameter.

Despite not strictly matching the tags, it may be worth mentioning that the interface semantics are slightly different in **Java**. The [`List` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) does not specifiy random access. The [`Iterable` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) though, which is the counterpart of `IEnumerable`, is similar.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that interfaces like `IEnumerable`, `ICollection` and `IList` (in generic and non-generic forms, though `ICollection` and `ICollection<T>` have little relation to each other) are best thought of ways by which objects can *allow themselves to be used* by code which is designed to do various things with sequences of items (which may be countable or addressable by index).  Code which simply wants to create a counted ordered sequence of items which is addressable by index can simply use `List<T>`, and can use that type whether or not it needs something which is counted and addressable by index, but an object which wants to make itself usable by code expecting a sequence of items can implement one of the above interfaces directly, rather than having to copy its contents to a new `List<T>` every time anybody wants enumerate them.

Note that one major advantage of `IEnumerable<T>` is that types which implement it do not have to hold the "entire contents" in memory, and can instead generate elements "on the fly".  If one has a method that does something with all the items in an `IEnumerable<T>`, and one wants to perform that action on every item in a 1,000,000-item list where `Fnord` is greater than 23 (which is true of 95% of the items), having the method accept `IEnumerable<T>` will avoid any need to create a 950,000-item list containing all the items where `Fnord` is greater than 23.