# IEnumerable in linq

Tags: linq, ienumerable

i have tow queries
one is

```
  List<int> Scores = new List<int>() { 97, 92, 81, 60 };
IEnumerable<int> queryHighScores =
            from a in Scores
            where a < 5
            select a;
```

and the other is

```
       int[] numbers = { 12, 43, 44, 323, 44, 45, 34 };
        var query1 = from a in numbers
                     where a < 5 
                     select a;
```

now anybody tell me what is IEnumerable and why we use  this . both query return same result so why we use IEnumerable

Comment: it has something to do with indexers

Comment: both queries return an `IEnumerable<int>`. If you _declare_ your variable with `var` or `IEnumerable<int>` is a matter of taste. Don't understand the question...

Comment: you can get all results here  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/832189/List-vs-IEnumerable-vs-IQueryable-vs-ICollection-v

Comment: why we cannot add more numbers in second query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IEnumerable vs List - What to Use? How do they work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work)

Comment: ok will you please tell what is the concept of IEnumerable

Comment: "Exposes an enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a non-generic collection."