# Cannot assign new value to LINQ-selected data

Tags: c#, linq, select, foreach

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class T1
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tmp = (new[] { 1, 3, 4 }).Select(x =>new T1 { MyProperty=x});
            foreach (var s in tmp)
            {
                s.MyProperty = 9;
            }
            foreach (var s in tmp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s.MyProperty);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I expect there are **three 9** on screen, but the values are still same.

However, if I modify code a little bit, the values would be changed successfully i.e. :

```
var tmp = (new[] { 1, 3, 4 }).Select(x =>new T1 { MyProperty=x}).ToList();
```

I wonder why?

Comment: you should read about [IEnumerable vs List in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is **deferred execution**.

`tmp` is *not a list or an array*. It's only a *definition how to create the enumeration*. Or in other words: `tmp` is only the *question*, but not the *answer*.

So in the second `foreach`, the enumerator created by the `Select` is executed **again**, creating **new** instances of `T1`.

When you use `.ToList()` instead, the enumeration is converted to a `List` (so `tmp` is a `List<T1>`). And you can iterate that `List` as often as you want without creating *new* instances.