# Changing Enumerated items aren't changed in original IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I noticed an issue with enumerating over a collection that was a result of a `.Select<T>()` I can enumerate over it, and modify each item in the collection. When I look at the collection after the enumeration is completed each item is left un-modified.

```
public class FooModel
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        IEnumerable<FooModel> foos = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
            .Select(m => new FooModel());

        foreach(FooModel f in foos)
        {
            f.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(foos.All(foo => foo.Id.HasValue));
    }
}
```

If I append `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` to execute the enumerable, then it modifies the items within the collection.

I understand that the `IEnumerable` isn't executed after the `.Select<T>`, but when the `foreach` runs it creates an enumerator and executes the IEnumerable on the foo local field. Why isn't it referencing the same object that the `Select<T>` creates?

I've seen questions on when to use `IEnumerable` over `List` but I understand the difference between the two. Describing vs implementing more or less. My question is more in regards to why the foreach over a local field, executes the IEnumerable and doesn't operate on the same objects referenced in the local variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IEnumerable vs List - What to Use? How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why isn't it referencing the same object that the Select creates?

Because `foo` is using `Enumerable.Range` which enumerates on-the-fly. There is no underlying data store that you are iterating over.

When you call `foreach` you are executing the underlying query, which creates 100 `FooModel` objects on the fly, which you modify.

When you call `.All`, you execute the query again, which creates *another* 100 `Foo` objects *on the fly* that have not been modified.

When you *hydrate* the results via `ToList` or `ToArray`, you are then looping over a *concrete collection*, and your changes to the underlying objects will persist.

Comment: I was wondering why Select had this side-effect but other LINQ methods like `Where<T>` doesn't. It makes sense that this is the case, since a `Select<T>` transform the object rather than just run a filter on the same series of objects.