# Cannot implicitly convert type, explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an error:

> (Cannot implicitly convert type 'shenoy webapi.Models.PartIndex' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) shenoywebapi D:\shenoystudio\shenoywebapi\Controllers\RateController.cs 69 Active)

```
[Route("api/Rate/getproductrate")]
public IEnumerable<Rate> GetProductRate()
{
    var list = new List<Rate>();
    var dsRate = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(AppDatabaseConnection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, 0, "GetProductRates");

    if (dsRate.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dsRate.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            list.Add(new Rate
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt64(row[0]),
                SerialNumber = row[1].ToString(),
                ProductName = row[2].ToString(),
                Unit = row[3].ToString(),
                PartIndex = new PartIndex { Series = row[4].ToString() },
            });
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

This is my model:

```
namespace shenoywebapi.Models
{
    public class Rate
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime wefDate { get; set; }
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public long Rates { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<PartIndex> PartIndex { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'shenoywebapi.Models.PartIndex' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  shenoywebapi    D:\shenoystudio\shenoywebapi\Controllers\RateController.cs  69  Active

Comment: Can you pinpoint which line is line 69?

Comment: Do you intend the `PartIndex` property to be a reference to a single `PartIndex` object, or a collection of them? Your `Rate` class expects a collection, but you're specifying a single value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this line

```
PartIndex = new PartIndex { Series = row[4].ToString() }
```

in your model `PartIndex` must be `IEnumerable<PartIndex>` it must be

```
PartIndex = new List<PartIndex>() { new PartIndex() {Series = row[4].ToString()} }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Rate class you have a property defined as:

```
public IEnumerable<PartIndex> PartIndex { get; set; }
```

In your function, you are trying to assign it as:

```
PartIndex = new PartIndex { Series = row[4].ToString() }
```

So you're trying to assign an object instead of an IEnumerable. Try to wrap the assignment in a `new List() {...}` to fix it.
The error also tells you about it pretty clearly:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'PartIndex' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Which means it cannot automatically cast a single object into an IEnumerable containing only that one object. You have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

First `IEnumerable<PartIndex>` can be create by `List<PartIndex>`
So create IEnumerable like

```
PartIndex = new List<PartIndex>();
```

And insert your element like :

```
PartIndex = new List<PartIndex>() { new PartIndex() {Series = row[4].ToString()} }
```

Last you can look that , It talk about IEnumrable and List .
[IEnumerable vs List - What to Use? How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work)