# Make List of Integers to Objects

Tags: c#, list, linq, generics, lambda

Is there a short form (maybe using `LINQ`) for making `integers` to `objects` and adding them into a `List`?

I imagine maybe something like `List<Car> TestList = car1.Neighbors.To(c => cars[c]);`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;                   
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Cars
        Car car0 = new Car(0, new List<int> { 1 });
        Car car1 = new Car(1, new List<int> { 0, 2 });
        Car car2 = new Car(2, new List<int> { 1 });
        List<Car> cars = new List<Car> { car0, car1, car2 };

        // THIS I WANT TO SHORTEN ▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼
        List<Car> TestList = new List<Car>();
        foreach (int i in car1.Neighbors)
            TestList.Add(cars[i]);
        // ▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲

        Console.Write("Neighbors of car 1:");
        foreach (Car car in TestList)
            Console.Write(" car" + car.Index);
    }   

    public class Car
    {
        public int Index; // index of the car
        public List<int> Neighbors; // car indexes, that are parked near to this car
        public Car (int index, List<int> neighbors)
        {
            Index = index;
            Neighbors = neighbors;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: linq is not much more than a glorified for loop, why specifically linq?  what exactly are you struggling with, why are you wishing to turn ints into objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Enumerable.Select` (from `System.Linq`) which projects each element of a sequence into a new form (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)

```
IEnumerable<Car> TestList = car1.Neighbors.Select(i => cars[i]);
```

or this if you absolutely need a List

```
List<Car> TestList = car1.Neighbors.Select(n => cars[n]).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! What is the advantage of an IEnumerable instead of a List?

Comment: Question already asked ;-), please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you're asking about something like `car1.Neighbors.Select(x => cars[i]).ToList()`, however; frankly, I would suggest storing a list of *references* rather than a list of *indices* - unless you have *very specific needs* (usually related to advanced indexing strategies). A `List<Car>` as `Neighbors` would work much more directly, and avoids a *lot* of problems. If you're on x86, it won't even cost anything extra; on x64, *yes* a 64-bit reference is a little bigger than a 32-bit integer, but: you're avoiding all the indirection and all the problems of index management. With that, this code becomes literally:

```cs
var neighbors = car1.Neighbors;
```

Comment: Thanks for the general hint! Maybe i implement this in my code!

Comment: Is this solution also practicable, if I want to delete or find a certain car from the list? maybe I want to delete car2 from the neighbor list of car1. How can I do this in your solution? In case, I have to search for the `car.index`, then I don't see an advantage for me

Comment: @Pixel_95 `car1.Neighbors.Remove(car2)`

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Car> TestList = new List<Car>(car1.Neighbors.Select(x => cars[x]));
```

Or

```
List<Car> TestList = new List<Car>(cars.Where(x => car1.Neighbors.Contains(x.Index)));
```

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen how come? I mean I know the "Index" property is not the same as the position in the array, but seeing OP's pattern it should work