# C# Linq to check duplicate values with dynamic column names

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a table in SQL server with 4 columns as shown below,

```
ID  ColName Value       Identifier
1   Name    Test User 1 A100
2   Country USA         A100
3   Name    Test User 2 A101
4   Gender  Male        A101
5   Country France      A101
6   Name    Test User 3 A102
7   Country USA         A102
8   Name    Test User 1 A103
9   Country USA         A103
```

Using C# Linq, I am trying to find out if a value already exists in the above table.
For example, let's say I have a value like,
Name = Test User 1 and Country = USA, how can i efficiently check if these values already exists in the above table?

I have tried an approach but, it is extremely slow with larger data in the table,

```
var userName = "Test User 1";
var country = "1-USA";

var results = records.SelectMany(x => x.UserDetails).Where(x => x.ColName.Equals("Name") && 
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value) && x.Value.Equals(userName )).ToList();

            if (results != null && results.Count > 0)
            {
                var identifiers = results.Select(x => x.Identifier).Distinct().ToList();

                var matchingCountries = records.SelectMany(x => x.UserDetails).
                Where(x => x.ColName.Equals("Country") && identifiers.Contains(x.Identifier)).ToList();

                var infoList = results.Select(x => new SearchInfoList { Name = x.Value, Identifier = x.Identifier,
                Country = (matchingCountries.Where(r => r.Identifier.Equals(x.Identifier)).Select(r => r.Value).FirstOrDefault()) }).ToList();

                infoList = infoList.Select(x => { x.Country = Helper.IncludeCode(codes, x.Country); return x; }).ToList();

                int recordCount = infoList.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(userName) && x.Country.Equals(country)).Count();


                if (recordCount > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Is there any simple way using C# Linq to check if there is a matching name/country combination with same identifier already exists in the above table?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many of the 'fields' have to match to be considered a duplicate. Name is obvious, but which other fields? is just 'country'?

Comment: @DaniDev Yes, Name and Country. There could be other fields too but, we need to match only 2 fields.

Comment: "s there any simple way using C# Linq to check if there is a matching name/country combination with same identifier already exists in the above table?" yes, you need to group by those to columns and check if you find any grouping that has more than 1 entry. This is a common approach

Comment: @MongZhu, could you please provide direction of how to do the grouping on this data?

Comment: yes, I found the duplicate that shows how to find duplicates ;)

Comment: @MongZhu, I am not sure if my question is a duplicate. In my case the data is different. And as I mentioned in the question, Name/country combination with same identifier is considered as a match.

Comment: Try like this. `var l = records.SelectMany(x => x.UserDetails); var y = l.Where(x => x.ColName.Equals("Name") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value) && x.Value.Equals(userName)).Join(l.Where(x => x.ColName.Equals("Country") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value) && x.Value.Equals(country)), name => name.Identifier, country => country.Identifier, (n, c) => new { Name = n, Country = c }).Any();`

Comment: Use `.ToList()` instead of `.Any()` if you want complete list. `.Any()` will just return `true/false` based on if match found or not.

Comment: @Karan, thanks for the code sample. Let me try and will update the status.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.Where` and `.Join` like below.

```
var userDetails = records.SelectMany(x => x.UserDetails);
var isExists = userDetails.Where(x => x.ColName.Equals("Name") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value) && x.Value.Equals(userName))
                          .Join(userDetails.Where(x => x.ColName.Equals("Country") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value) && x.Value.Equals(country)), 
                                name => name.Identifier,
                                country => country.Identifier, 
                                (n, c) => new { Name = n, Country = c })
                          .Any();
```

---

To make above code more readable you can get `Enumerable` object for `names` & `countries` like below. **Note** that do not use `.ToList()` while you get value in `names` & `countries` object for better performance. Because `.ToList()` will immediately evaluate condition and allocate memory for result while `Enumerable` object will only evaluate when required (i.e in this case it will evaluate with `.Join`). You can refer [IEnumerable vs List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3628606/9695286)

```
var names = records.SelectMany(x => x.UserDetails).Where(x => x.ColName.Equals("Name") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value) && x.Value.Equals(userName));
var countries = records.SelectMany(x => x.UserDetails).Where(x => x.ColName.Equals("Country") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value) && x.Value.Equals(country));
var isExists = names.Join(countries, 
                          name => name.Identifier,
                          country => country.Identifier, 
                          (n, c) => new { Name = n, Country = c })
                    .Any();
```