# MongoDB C# Case Insensitive Sort and Index

Tags: c#, mongodb, sorting, indexing

So far I've been using this code to find my documents and then sort them:

```
        var options = new FindOptions
        {
            Modifiers = new BsonDocument("$hint", "PathTypeFilenameIndex")
        };

        return await Collection
            .Find(f => f.Metadata["path"] == path, options)
            .SortBy(f => f.Metadata["type"])
            .ThenBy(f => f.Filename)
            .ToListAsync();
```

I have a class that has Metadata field with path and type fields, also the class has a Filename field. I want all documents with a given path inside the metadata sorted by type and then by Filename.

An example result would be a list of documents ordered by the Name field like this:

```
a, Ab, B, c, D
```

Unfortunately, I get something like this:

```
Ab, B, D, a, c
```

And that's because MongoDB sorts the data with a simple binary comparison, where 'A' < 'a' because of their ASCII codes.

So my question is: **Is there a way to make a case insensitive sort and keep using the "$hint"?**

That options I pass to the Find method should tell MongoDB which index to use. I found this post: [MongoDB and C#: Case insensitive search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458950/mongodb-and-c-case-insensitive-search) but the method here doesn't work for sorting and I couldn't tell MongoDB which index to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use aggregation pipeline with `$addFields`, `$toLower` (to convert filename to lowercase in temporary field), and `$sort` to sort them irrespective of the case

In mongodb shell you would write something like this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $addFields : {
        "lowercaseFileName" : {
            $loLower : "$fileName"
        }
    },{
        $sort : {
            "metadata.type" : 1,
            lowercaseFileName : 1
        }
    }
}])
```

Please write the similar code in c#, and see if it works. I dont know c#, otherwise i would have given you the exact query, but i cant.

The idea is to transform the filename to lowercase, save it in temporary field, using addFields and sort by that field.

Hope this helps you out.

Read more about [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/), [$toLower](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/) here.

**Update**

For whoever wants a working code in C# , thanks to [@kaloyan-manev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9665681/kaloyan-manev)

You can use this :

```
return await Collection.Aggregate()
    .Match(f => f.Metadata["path"] == path) 
    .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("$addFields", new BsonDocument("lowercaseFileName", new BsonDocument("$toLower", "$filename")))) 
    .AppendStage<GridFSFileInfo>(new BsonDocument("$sort", new BsonDocument { {"metadata.type", 1}, {"lowercaseFileName", 1} }))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and I will write back.

Comment: Add this code to your answer if you want:
return await Collection.Aggregate() 
            .Match(f => f.Metadata["path"] == path)
            .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("$addFields",
                new BsonDocument("lowercaseFileName",
                    new BsonDocument("$toLower", "$filename"))))
            .AppendStage<GridFSFileInfo>(new BsonDocument("$sort",
                new BsonDocument
                {
                    {"metadata.type", 1},
                    {"lowercaseFileName", 1}
                })).ToListAsync();

Comment: Also, there is no need to add the $hint, mongo is smart enough to use the right index.

Comment: Yes i would agree on that, mongodb is smart enough to use the right index

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to set the CollationStrenght = 2?

Your code would be similar all you need is to set the Collation in the FindObject:

```
 var options = new FindOptions
    {
        Modifiers = new BsonDocument("$hint", "PathTypeFilenameIndex"),
        Collation = new Collation("en", strength: CollationStrength.Secondary)
    };
```