# Linq not showing correct number

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq like this:

```
IQueryable<Rentals> rentals = from r in context.Rentals
                              select r;


foreach (Rentals r in rentals)
{
    str +=  r.ListingID + "|";             
}
```

but `str` has only 50 records while, if I do `rentals.Count()`, it shows 1700. I tried to debug and saw that the flow of control goes out of the `foreach` loop after the 50th record. Why is that so?

Comment: well, it can't be **both** LINQ-to-SQL **and** EF... which is it? Also: not key to the question, but you should look at `StringBuilder` here (for the concatenation-in-a-loop etc)

Comment: Don't have the answer, but consider using `StringBuilder` when doing string concatenation operations in a loop.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram : it is not concatenation issue. control exits after 50 iterations. It can be time out issue. as rentals are picked from service ?

Comment: I would say consider using `string.Join` rather than `StringBuilder` here

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: They aren't saying it's a concatenation issue, that's why they posted as comments instead of answers. They are just saying there are more efficient ways to concatenate then using pure string concatenation.

Comment: Do you have a try/catch around this code?

Comment: @Jason: I first tried stringbuilder but was checking if it is stringbuilder's length issue that's why i used string. thanks for clarification

Comment: try doing foreach (Rentals r in rentals.ToList()) which will force the query execution and see how many records you got

Comment: Try `var str = string.Join("|", rentals);` instead of doing the looping yourself. By the way, the error could be due to timeout issues with the database. Have you tried `rentals.ToArray()`?

Comment: Can you post the query run on both the count and the foreach loop, you can get this using sql profiler thanks

Comment: Instead of string.Join or using a StringBuilder use  `rentals.Aggregate("", (all,n)=>all + n.ListingID + "|")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Rentals> rentals = (from r in context.Rentals
                              select r).ToList();
```

Try creating a list first and check if that works. Also, use a `StringBuilder()` to build. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I used above ToList and I get rental.count = 50, but If I try to use without ToList, It gives 1362 record count but shows 50. whats is error ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<Rentals> rentals = context.Rentals.ToList();

str = Enumerable.Aggregate(rentals, str, (current, r) => current + (r.ListingID + "|"));
```

It's more efficient that the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to change your code to be the following?

```
IEnumerable<Rentals> rentals = from r in context.Rentals
                               select r;
```

Comment: Since `IQueryable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`, he is.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `IQueryable<T>`, your results will be first prepared as an sql statement (using expression trees) and then executed and would be processed out-of-process (server side), but if you use .ToList() on the result or use `IEnumerable<T>` return type - your results would be executed using LINQ to Objects (in-memory) which is what Count is doing.

Try to check the `Expression` property of `rentals` variable when using `IQueryable<T>` as return value. I am still not sure why the number of records are different, but the below links explain the difference and the usage of `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erickt/archive/2006/10/23/iqueryable-t-vs-ienumerable-t.aspx

http://jonkruger.com/blog/2007/10/19/iqueryable-vs-ienumerable-in-linq-to-sql-queries/

[Returning IEnumerable<T> vs. IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet)