# How to write LINQ statement for XmlAttributeCollection?

Tags: c#, linq, asenumerable, asqueryable, xmlattributecollection

I always confuse AsQueryable, AsEnumerable.
When should I use them? Should I use AsQueryable to create a LINQ statement to make a filter according to attribute of xml or AsEnumerable?

```
[Serializable]
public class LogHandler : IConfigurationSectionHandler
{
    public object Create(object parent, object configContext, XmlNode section)
    {
        XmlAttributeCollection v = section.Attributes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet

Comment: Could you add some more detail about what you're trying to achieve in the code snippet that you posted?

Answer (score 2):

The primary difference is that the extension methods defined for IQueryable take Expression objects instead of Func objects, meaning the delegate it receives is an expression tree instead of a method to invoke. **IEnumerable** is great for working with **in-memory collections**, but **IQueryable** allows for a **remote data source**, like a database or web service.