# Is IEnumerable a good return type for data that allows filtering?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, iqueryable

I just read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet) and it got me thinking of why I would need to use the `IEnumerable` when retrieving data.  I understand the differences between `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable`, but would an `IEnumerable` object be better for data that allows filtering?  for example, a table with the records which contain a date, so I can sort on the date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the objects in memory - not from another data source such as a database - use `IEnumerable<T>`. That way the built in LINQ to Objects will work automatically.

You could even extend LINQ to Objects by writing custom extension methods and using `yield return` and `yield break`.

If you are using Entity Framework or some other system that is using `IQueryable<T>`, I would keep it as `IQueryable<T>` until you need it as objects.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you want to First recieve all Data and afterwards filter the returned Set of **Objects** use IEnumerable.

If you want to enable Filtering on the Database (e.g. Linq-to-sql / Entity Framework) better use IQueryable.