# Resharper, "Return type can be IEnumerable..." but why?

Tags: c#, resharper

I have an interface like so...

```
public interface IAccountRepository : IDisposable {
    IQueryable<Account> FindByUserId(int userId); //here, Resharper says "Return type can be IEnumerable<Account>"
}
```

But Resharper is suggesting me to change it to `IEnumerable<Account> FindByUserId(int userId)` instead.

Why is that so? Wouldn't it force the entire objects to be loaded into memory? I thought it would be better to defer the execution until the object is really needed?

Comment: It not loaded in memory until you execute methods like `.Count()` or `.ToList()`, for example.

Comment: It will be because nothing in your solution uses any of the `IQueryable<T>` methods on objects returned by `FindByUserId`, so R# suggests you can make the return type more general.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault IQueryable allows further refining of the query (`.Where...`) without pre-emptively loading the result into object in memory. Obviously this is not the case for IEnumerable right?

Comment: @RosdiKasim You make a good point which I apparently did not consider completely in my answer. But the `Where` method is an extension method on `IEnumerable` anyway [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx), so you are still not losing any power (even though I am not immediately sure how to override an extension method). Or am I missing something about `IQuerable`?

Comment: @Porges You are correct nothing in my solution is using `IQueryable<T>` methods **yet**, but that does not mean it will not be used in the future, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @RosdiKasim: R# can't know what you will do in the future :), it's just a suggestion based upon the state of your project. I'll post an answer.

Comment: [This page in the R# documentation is for a different message, but relevant](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Parameter+type+can+be+IEnumerable+of+T).

Comment: @TimSchmelter That question you linked too is asking about method parameter, I am asking about return type. I am trying to understand why Resharper giving me that suggestion.

Comment: @RosdiKasim The suggestion is for the same reason in both cases. The value (the parameter or return value) used *can* be a less derived type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just a specific instance of a general rule.

If you are returning a type `SomeClass` which implements an interface or inherits from another class, and in your entire solution you only use methods on the returned object which are in the base class/interface (so you don't use any methods declared in `SomeClass`), ReSharper will suggest that you replace the type of the returned object with that of the base class/interface in order to make your code more general.

In this case, you are only using methods of the `IEnumerable<T>` interface that `IQueryable<T>` derives from.

Note also that this is just a *suggestion*, not a warning or an error. You can safely ignore this if you want to.

Comment: +1 *Return type can be `IEnumerable`* simply means that the return type *can* be `IEnumerable` not that it *should* be.

Comment: Thanks.. I just want to make sure I understand what I am doing instead of following R# suggestions blindly.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is "no, **BUT**".

Casting it to IEnumerable does not force execution. Operators in the IEnumerable space (like the "Where" method) can still be lazily evaluated.

But there is some caveat here. If you, inside this method, start to use LINQ operators, then LINQ will choose the Enumerable LINQ operators like [GroupBy (IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) instead of Queryable operators like [GroupBy (IQueryable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534492.aspx). Notice that they differ in their parameter list.

The effect of this is that your passed Lambda expression will be converted to a Func instead of an Expression> (note the difference in the parameter list of the two respective methods). So your lambda will not be an expression tree, which is what Queryable sources need in order to translate it to SQL (or similar) so that the query can be passed over the server and executed server side.

So, your query will be slower. Not because it will execute once you cast it, but because the whole datasource will be pulled over to the client once you start trying to get items off of it.

This is, of course, only if start using LINQ (attaching "Where" clauses or something) inside this method. If you don't, you're fine.

Comment: That means it is possible I will be moving insanely large amount of results into memory to be filtered right? That is what I understand from this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2876655/193634

Comment: Any LINQ operators that you use inside of this method will not be able to execute server side.

Comment: @RosdiKasim it's possible if you return insanely large datasets from your repository, but why on earth would you do that? `IQueryable` is a leaky abstraction if there ever was one, so you want to limit the result set as early as possible and only deal with `IEnumerable`s in the service layer.

Answer (score 1):

`IQueryable` already inherits from `IEnumerable` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx)), so any objection that you have to `IEnumerable` will still be there. ReSharper is indicating that the method might as well be defined to return `IEnumerable` even if all implementations return `IQueryable` (if a call needed an `IQueryable` instead of an `IEnumerable` they can just call `AsQueryable` too [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734.aspx))

Also members of an `IEnumerable` are only retrieved as they are enumerated, which means that e.g. even if each member was obtained by a separate web service call, those calls will only be made when the particular member is requested.

Comment: From what I understand, they behave differently, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2876655/193634