# Why does resharper suggest: "Return type can be IEnumerable<T>"?

Tags: .net, generics, collections, resharper

I am new to Resharper and loving it. However, it recently suggested something which didn't make sense to me, and I'm wondering why it made the suggestion. I've disabled it in Resharper, but am wondering if there's something I'm missing...

I wrote a function with a signature: `List<string> DoSomething()`

Resharper suggested I change this to: `IEnumerable<string> DoSomething()`.

Now I can understand why the parameters of a method must be as generic as possible. It helps the code be more reusable etc. However, I try and make sure the data returned by my methods is specific rather than generic.

Could someone please explain why Resharper suggested what it did?

(To find the rule, go to Resharper Options \ Code Inspection \ Inspection Severity, and search for: "Return type can be IEnumerable".)

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17904644/57005

Comment: Thanks! I tried googling for "Return type can be IEnumerable<T>" but that answer didn't show up for some reason. The other page "Resharper suggests parameter can be of type 'BaseType'" did show up in my google search, but that wasn't what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several reasons why you might want to have a more generic return type.

The more generic type allows you more freedom to change the implementation of the method without changing the method interface. With a return type of `IEnumerable<string>` you can for example choose to use a `string[]` instead of a `List<string>` to produce the return value.

Using a more generic type offers some protection for the data. If the method returns a list that exists as a private member in the class, the person calling the method could change the returned list without realising that it changes the list inside the class. When you return an `IEnumerable<string>` that can only be used to iterate the items, it doesn't give access to change the list.

It's clearer how the more limited return type should be used. It's natural to assume that an `IEnumerable<string>` is supposed to be iterated, but a `List<string>` can be used in many different ways.

Comment: I agree that for interfaces, IEnumerable would make more sense (since different implementations might use different implementations of IEnumerable (like list, or array, etc)). However the way I looked at it was: If my class returns a List instead of an IEnumerable, the returned data can be used with other methods which accept List instead of IEnumerable as their parameters.

Comment: Is this a case of "use as appropriate"? Or is it a better idea to think of this as a general rule and modify all my methods to accept IEnumerables instead of Lists? I used lists because I felt performance would be better...

Comment: @Omaer: Resharper suggests that you should change the type because you are actually only using it as an enumerable. You shouldn't change all methods to use `IEnumerable<>`, but rather just consider where that would be a better fit than a `List<>`. There is no difference in performance at all between passing a `List<>` and an `IEnumerable<>`, the only difference is what the compiler allows you to do with it.

Comment: Sorry for taking your time, and thank you for helping. Here's what I mean: void Method2(List<string> data); accepts a list, and uses List methods (like Add etc). Now, the List returned from my previous method needs to be passed into Method2 (which requires a List). Is it a better idea to return an IEnumerable, convert it to a list, and pass that list into Method2? Or does it make more sense to ignore Resharper and just return a List? (I have a lot of methods which work with lists, and some which don't. And they all work with each other).

Comment: @Omaer: If you are actually using the list as a list and not just iterating it, there is no point in passing it as an `IEnumerable<>`. Another way to handle the lists that you could consider would be to encapsulate the list in a class, and let the methods of the class work with the list.

Comment: That's a great idea - I think I'll do that instead. Thanks @Guffa!