# Using LINQ to Entity without putting all rows in memory

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I use this method to get each page of data from EF:

```
public IEnumerable<MyObj> GetByPage(int page, int perPage)
{
    return context.MyObj.Skip((page - 1) * perPage).Take(perPage);
}
```

I want to know ;would this code fetch all rows of `MyObj` and store in memory and then will `Skip` and `Take` or all of above code will translate to SQL command?

If all first will store in memory,How can I use LINQ to entity to not to use memory to `Skip` and `Take`?

Comment: Consider returning `IQueryable<MyObj>` too so that the calling code can add additional query operations to be performed in the backing data store (whereas `IEnumerable<MyObj>` will cause those operations to be performed by the CLR, after the query returns from the data store).

Comment: @cdhowie I saw in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2876655/2040375 that says " If you use Take and Skip on IQueryable, you will only get the number of rows requested; doing that on an IEnumerable<T> will cause all of your rows to be loaded in memory". what about this?

Comment: That's half-true.  The `Skip()` operation would force all of the skipped-over records to be fetched and then discarded, one-by-one.  The `Take()` operation will dispose of its enumerator after it has fetched the specified number of rows, so the rows after those you fetch *may not necessarily* be fetched from disk by the database server, nor returned to the database client in your application.  (But they might, depending on the database and client library implementations.)

Comment: It's important to note that depending on the client library implementation, all of the records might exist in memory, but if they are read one-by-one by the client library then each skipped-over record is eligible for garbage collection *immediately* after it is processed.  So if the client library is smart then you still wouldn't be loading the entire result set into memory; the entire overhead would consist of fetching and discarding all of the skipped-over records (which would increase processing time, but not necessarily significant memory usage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `Skip` and `Take` are listed as [LINQ to Entities supported methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx), so they will be transformed into proper SQL statements and only necessary rows will be retrieved from database.

And because your method returns `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IQueryable<T>` every call to the query returned from that method will cause query execution.

Comment: I saw in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2876655/2040375 that says " If you use Take and Skip on IQueryable, you will only get the number of rows requested; doing that on an IEnumerable<T> will cause all of your rows to be loaded in memory". what about this against your last paragraph?

Comment: @MajidR You're doing it on `IQueryable`, because `context.MyObj` is `IQueryable`. But because your method returns `IEnumerable` everything that is done on an object returned from your method will be done on `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 7):

As long as you're not materializing the query (i.e calling `ToList()`/`ToArray()` etc, or iterating over it), your `Skip` and `Take` method will be translated to SQL by the Linq to Entities provider that is part of the Entity Framework.

So to answer your question: no, it won't fetch all data and load it into memory.

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633.aspx) for a full explanation.

Comment: I saw in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2876655/2040375 that says " If you use Take and Skip on IQueryable, you will only get the number of rows requested; doing that on an IEnumerable<T> will cause all of your rows to be loaded in memory". what about this?

Comment: That is correct. because calling `Skip` on an `IEnumerable` will execute the `Linq to Objects`.`Skip` method (rather than `Linq to Entities`.`Skip`) that will have to materialize the collection. same goes for `Where`/`Select` etc.

Comment: so if I save result of some linq to entity query in `IEnumerable<T>`var;next linq on this var,will not fetching database? what if I use `IQueryable<T>`?

Comment: Generally, yes. but if `Proxy Creation` is enabled by the Context, you may still hit the database when loading `Navigation Properties` data.

Answer (score 2):

`Skip` and `Take` will be evaluated and then the result will be stored to memory, so it will not hold the whole data set in memory.  This is called [Deferred Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it depends on your data store, but for SQL Server it would not pull any records not defined in that query.  In the case of T-SQL, the TOP predicate is used to "skip" records.