# Entity framework navigation property FirstOrDefault()

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-5

I have the following line:

```
WorkPlaces.FirstOrDefault()
    .WorkSteps.Where(x=>x.Failcodes_Id != null)
    .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Timestamp)
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

There are about 10-20 workplaces and each workplace have thousands of worksteps. I would like to get the last workstep for each of the workplaces.
The code above is an example from linqpad because I couldn't believe that the generated sql looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[Active] AS [Active], 
[Extent1].[ProductionLine_Id] AS [ProductionLine_Id], 
[Extent1].[DefaultTechnology_Id] AS [DefaultTechnology_Id], 
[Extent1].[PrinterName] AS [PrinterName], 
[Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
[Extent1].[LoggedInUser_UserId] AS [LoggedInUser_UserId]
FROM  [dbo].[WorkPlaces] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[WorkplaceParameterSet] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[WorkPlace_Id]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @EntityKeyValue1 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[WorkPlace_Id] AS [WorkPlace_Id], 
[Extent1].[WorkItemState_Id] AS [WorkItemState_Id], 
[Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
[Extent1].[WorkItem_Id] AS [WorkItem_Id], 
[Extent1].[Technology_Id] AS [Technology_Id], 
[Extent1].[Failcodes_Id] AS [Failcodes_Id], 
[Extent1].[DrawingNo] AS [DrawingNo], 
[Extent1].[ManualData] AS [ManualData], 
[Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
[Extent1].[WorkItemState_Arrival_Id] AS [WorkItemState_Arrival_Id]
FROM [dbo].[WorkSteps] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[WorkPlace_Id] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

Is there a way to get one line from worksteps without downloading 9000 records to pick one from the top of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than getting each workplace individually and then getting the workstep for that work place in a query you can use `Select` to project each workplace into the workstep that you want in one query:

```
var query = WorkPlaces.Select(workplace => workplace.WorkSteps
    .Where(x => x.Failcodes_Id != null)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp)
    .FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Firstordefault -> top for the navigation property is working now, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You should use `IQueryable` interface instead of `IEnumerable`. Also check [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet)

Comment: He already is.  If he wasn't, it wouldn't be generating SQL as he showed that it is.