# EntityFramework - Sum() Causing OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an MVC application, which uses EntityFramework to connect to MS SQL Server 2012. I am trying to retrieve the total file size of all documents stored in the Documents table.

I am using the following code:

```
this.Documents.Sum(x => x.FileSize);
```

Where Documents is of type `EntityCollection<Document>`. The operation is taking over 1.6 minutes to complete, at which point it crashes with

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

Surely this is just the same as doing `SELECT SUM(FileSize) FROM Documents` which takes just a few milliseconds to complete when executed directly via SQL Server Management Studio.

For what it's worth, the total size is 816mb, and includes 1,661 documents, so it's not exactly massive.

Comment: Have you attached sql profiler and examined the query that's being sent?

Comment: Are you maybe doing a ToList() on this.Documents somewhere before? Because if it's already in memory then the Sum will be executed client side...

Comment: if its only the sum try this.Documents.Select(c => c.FileSize).Sum() instead so you dont fetch too much data

Comment: Or you can try this.Documents.Select(c => c.Sum(i => i.FileSize))

Answer (score 1):

It seems clear to me that `EntityCollection<Document>` is lazily loading every `Document` in the database. If your Document entity has blob data that would explain everything. Assuming you have an instance of `DbContext`, I would retrieve an instance of `DbSet<Document>` so you can write something like this:

```
var result = (from d in documents
              select new { Size = d.FileSize }).Sum(x => x.Size);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute your `Sum()` query on the database, make sure your `Documents` property is of `IQueryable<Document>` instead of `IEnumerable<Document>`. The former will translate your LINQ query into SQL (i.e. it will be translated to `SELECT SUM(FileSize)`) while the latter will be LINQ-to-objects, which will be done in memory.

You can refer to this answer for more information: [Returning IEnumerable<T> vs. IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet)

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be caused by lazy loading, as mentioned in the previous answers, however none of the suggested methods appear to work. However creating a new DB entity and querying directly appears to work fine:

```
MyEntities entities = new MyEntities();
decimal size = entities.Documents.Where(x => x.UniverseID == this.ID).Sum(x => x.FileSize);
```

I'm not sure what the difference is, but it seems to work!