# Unable to return query result as a specific type

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have been getting the error message below in the GetStudentById method below.
"cannot convert system.linq.iqueryable to target type system.collections.generic.list"

Que: Why cant I return my result as a list of studentDto

```
public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository
{
    private TechCollegeEducationEntities db = new TechCollegeEducationEntities();

    public List<StudentDto> GetStudentById(string studentId)
    {
        List<StudentDto> objresult = from c in db.Students
            where c.StudentId == 1
            select c;
        return objresult;

    }

    public List<StudentDto> GetAllStudents()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is my Dto

```
public class StudentDto
{
    public Int32 StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

I  just tried this now and it works for me..

```
   return (from c in db.Students
                select new StudentDto
                {
                    FirstName = c.FirstName,
                    LastName = c.LastName,
                    Department = c.Department,
                    EmailAddress = c.EmailAddress
                }).ToList()
```

Comment: Please post *exact* error message. As it stands now answer by Cuong Le is most you can expect.

Comment: I did. Here you go "cannot convert system.linq.iqueryable to target type system.collections.generic.list"

Comment: Not sure what you are using to write C# code, but Microsoft's C# compiler/VS gives more detailed error including types - something like "..IQueryable<...> to System.Collection.Generic.List<StudentDto> ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is LINQ returns `IQueryable<T>`, not `List<T>`, and  `IQueryable<T>` cannot *automatically* convert to `List<T>`.

In your example if you really want to return `List<T>`, just call to `ToList()`:

```
 List<StudentDto> objresult = db.Students.Where(c => c.StudentId == 1)
                                .Select(c => new StudentDto { 
                                       FirstName = c.FirstName, 
                                       LastName = c.LastName, 
                                       Department = c.Department, 
                                       EmailAddress = c.EmailAddress })
                                .ToList();
 return objresult;
```

Example above using Lambda syntax since I always feel it's more readable than LINQ syntax.

But this way is not really best practice since it does not support deferred execution. Instead of returning `List<T>`, you should return `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` directly.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
public interface IQueryable<out T> : IEnumerable<T>, IQueryable, IEnumerable
```

That's why `IEnumerable<T>` can be used.

One thing you also should notice the difference between `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` from this answer for your decision which should be used:

[Returning IEnumerable<T> vs. IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet)

Comment: Thanks. I just tried the code you sent but it does not work. i still get the same error message

Comment: return (from c in db.Students
                    select new StudentDto
                    {
                        FirstName = c.FirstName,
                        LastName = c.LastName,
                        Department = c.Department,
                        EmailAddress = c.EmailAddress
                    }).ToList()

Comment: @user2320476: You are right, I have edited my answer, since from your method you returns StudentDto, not Student