# Why DbSet<t>.Where() used IQueryable version by default?

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first, ienumerable, iqueryable

Whenever we want to use IEnumerable extension methods instead IQueryable version, we have use AsEnumerable() method.

```
var list = context.Details.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Code == "A1").ToList();
```

Why DbSet used IQueryable version of methods Like(Where , Select ,...) by default when other version available?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2876655/4074984

Comment: Cause when you call an extension method (or even instance method) on an object, and the object cannot provide that by itself, the run-time will look up parents one after another until find the method. In your case, the provided `IQueryable Where()` (or any others) method comes first. So it will be raised

Answer (score 5):

You'd usually *want* to use the `IQueryable` form, so that the filtering is done on the database instead of locally.

The code you've got will pull *all* records down to the client, and filter them there - that's extremely inefficient. You should only use `AsEnumerable()` when you're trying to do something that *can't* be performed in the database - usually after providing a server-side filter. (You may be able to do a coarse filter on the server, then a more fine-grained filter locally - but at least then you're not pulling *all* the records...)

Answer (score 2):

Because `IQuaryable` methods are translated into `SQL` by Entity Framework.But `IEnumerable` method are not.So if you use `IEnumearable` all the data will be fetched from `DB` which is not always what you want.