# Return IQueryable<T> from my method? Is it the right way to do it?

Tags: c#, linq, expression, iqueryable

I just spent some time to find how to return an IQueryable from a method... and I'm still wondering if it is the right way to do it.

Here is my repository class:

```
public class CarRepository : ICarRepository
{
    // Fake entities
    private IList<Car> _entities = new List<Car>()
    {
        new Car() { Brand = "Lamborghini", Name = "Huracán"},
        new Car() { Brand = "BMW", Name = "X6" }
    };

    // Allows deferred execution/further refinement
    public IQueryable<Car> FindByQueryable(Expression<Func<Car, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var query = _entities.Where(predicate.Compile()).AsQueryable();
        return query;
    }

    // Returning an IList or IEnumerable
    public IList<Car> FindBy(Expression<Func<Car, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _entities.Where(predicate.Compile()).ToList();
    }
}
```

At first I thought that something like that should work, but it was not compiling:

```
    public IQueryable<Car> FindByQueryable(Expression<Func<Car, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var query = _entities.Where(predicate);
        return query;
    }
```

Am I right with the predicate.Compile() and .AsQueryable?

Thanks for you help!
Bastien

Comment: I would rather return `IEnumerable<Car>` instead of `IQueryable`.

Comment: @AlexSikilinda IQueryable<T> is a [better choice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet) for Databases. However I disapprove of this in general, I think a Repository that returns IQueryables is of low value (may as well just use the EF/LtSql etc linq provider directly and your abstractions will leak in palaces you don't expect [for example, in the case of EF, is it clear what data remains tracked?).

Comment: It's ok like this. Leave the responsibility to the Dal layer which will interact with the repository. In the dal layer you then call ToList, when you have finished the total query construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stand it makes no sense. If you want to use `Queryable` methods to remote queries into the database you must use expression trees. Using `Compile` converts a tree to a delegate which destroys this opportunity.

`_entities` must be an `IQueryable<T>` in order to target `Queryable` methods.

`AsQueryable` is a code smell that usually indicates the mistakes describe above. This is a fake queryable. It is in-memory (except if the source is really IQueryable; then it does a cast).

Answer (score 2):

The reason

```
var query = _entities.Where(predicate);
```

fails is because `_entities` only implements `IEnumerable<Car>`, not `IQueryable<Car>`. The [`Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` takes a `Func<T, bool>`. The [`Queryable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535040%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method for `IQueryable<T>` takes an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

Instead of manually compiling your expression trees, you can move `AsQueryable()` a bit up:

```
var query = _entities.AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
```

As usr's answer rightly points out, this doesn't usually make sense, since it'll use local filtering, never any server-side filtering. However, there are exceptions where it does make sense, and your case may be one such exception: if you have multiple implementations of `ICarRepository`, some local, some remote, then it may make perfect sense to do it the way you're doing. You wouldn't want the user of `ICarRepository` to have to deal with the question of whether to use delegates or expression trees: the user should just use expression trees, your `CarRepository` can then pass those expression trees to some query provider, and that query provider can then choose whether to compile them to delegates, or to translate them to some other language such as SQL.