# NpGsql EntityFramework 6 - "An operation is already in progress"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

I am working on a project to connect to PostgreSQL database using NpGsql EntityFramework 6. I am getting the exception in question heading, when I try to execute the query in `GetAdminUsersCount`:

```
public class GenieRepository : IDisposable
{
    GenieDbContext db = new GenieDbContext();
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return db.Users;
    }   
}

public int GetAdminUsersCount()
{
    return repo.GetUsers().Where(u => u.Role.RoleName == "Administrator").Count();
}
```

What is the reason for this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: SideNote: **PostGre Sql** :O,huh??? Use [Postgres or PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info)

Comment: Which version of NpgSql do you use? If you deploy on mono which version is it?

Comment: NpgSql 3.0.4.0, Entity Framework 6.0

Comment: Similar issue was found in Mono 3.x but was solved after upgrade to 4.x. Try to downgrade to NpgSql 2.2.7

Comment: seeing the same issue, EF 6.1.3, NpgSql 3.0.5

Comment: There is an open defect at https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/826. We see this on Mono 4.2.2

Answer (score 8):

Use a `ToList<T>` right after the LINQ query like this:

```cs
using (ElisContext db = new ElisContext()) {
    var q = from a in db.aktie select a;
    List<aktie> akties = q.ToList<aktie>();
    foreach (aktie a in akties) {
        Console.WriteLine("aktie: id {0}, name {1}, market name {2}"
                 , a.id, a.name, a.marked.name);
    }
}
```

Note the `q.ToList<T>` which does the trick. .NET delays the execution of the linq statement to the latest moment, which may be part of the problem. I have tried to use `q` in the `foreach` without success.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is caused by the return type of the `GetUsers()` method. Since it is `IEnumerable<User>`, LINQ-to-SQL will load the result into memory (row by row) and subsequent `Where`, `OrderBy`, `Select`, `Count`, etc. calls will be executed in memory. When the `Where` condition is evaluated, the original result set is still being iterated over, but the relation `User.Role` needs to be resolved on the DB (that's where the "An operation is already in progess" error message comes from).

If the return type is changed to `IQueryable<User>`, the query won't be executed until the `Count` method is called, and furthermore, the whole query will be translated into SQL returning only the count without ever loading any `User` records into memory.

See also this related question/answer: [Returning IEnumerable<T> vs. IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet)

The answer suggesting to call `ToList()` on the query, will load the entire result set into memory, which makes your error go away, but depending on the size of the result set, could also be very inefficient.