# Does not contain definition for 'Contains'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

It is showing the error like "doesn't contain definition for ID" for the code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult show(List<int> ids)
    {
        if (ids != null)
        {
            int[] brands = ids.ToArray();
            var brandId = _db.Brands.Where(p => brands.Contains(p.ID));
            var srtItems = _db.Products.Where(p => p.CategoryID == brandId.ID);

            return PartialView("_pView", srtItems);
        }
    }
```

and for the following code the error is' doesn't contain definition for Contains'

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult show(List<int> ids)
        {
            if (ids != null)
            {
                int[] brands = ids.ToArray();
                var brandId = _db.Brands.Where(p => brands.Contains(p.ID));

                var sortItemss = _db.Products.Where(p => brandId.Contains(p.CategoryID));
                return PartialView("_pView", srtItems);
            }
```

Please guide me

Comment: @diiN_ Sure he did, otherwise he wouldn't be able to use `Where`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is where `var` becomes the root of all evil as it hides the real data type. Drop the var and you'll notice the problem immediately:

```
int[] brands = ids.ToArray();
IQueryable<Brand> brandId = _db.Brands.Where(p => brands.Contains(p.ID));
IQueryable<Product> srtItems = _db.Products.Where(p => p.CategoryID == brandId.ID);
```

`brandId` is a sequence (when materialized) and it is not a single object, so it doesn't contains a definition of `ID`.

To solve that, you can:

```
IQueryable<int> brandIds = _db.Brands.Where(p=> brands.Contains(p.ID)).Select(b=> b.ID);
IQueryable<Product> srtItems = _db.Products.Where(p=> brandIds.Contains( p.CategoryID));
```

Get the IDs of the retrieved records, and match by those IDs.

**As an advice**, don't use `var` unless the real type is redundant (meaning it shows in other parts of the statement)

Comment: Bad advice. Both your `var` "replacements" changed the real type from `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @IvanStoev Absolutely correct about the second part, but not about the advice! I did that in a hurry, but if someone does this intentionally then that does mean he doesn't know what the method returns.. We should not be using a method that we don't know its signature I guess. Otherwise, we need to fully understand the difference between `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` and *What gets executed Where and When*

Comment: @user3185569, sir can you please explain what difference does it make between IEnumerable and IQueryable. I mean when to use each of them.

Comment: @pavan That question already has good answers.. One of which: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @user3185569, Sir, can guide please me for this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944709/using-distinct-in-lambda-expression-and-use-it-in-foreach-loop/40944866#40944866