# How to call method with Expression of type Func as parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression, func

I used Repository pattern that I saw on online tutorial...

Everything works fine except for find method, I have no idea how to work with this and I'm having hard time understanding Expressions or Func types. I used linq and lambda before but I'm begginer and still don't use it fluently...

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
}
```

I have this model class:

```
public partial class Artikl
{
        [Browsable(false)]
        public int IDArtikli { get; set; }
        public string Barkod { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Šifra")]
        public Nullable<int> Sifra { get; set; }
        public string Naziv { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("JM")]
        public string JedinicaMjere { get; set; }
        public decimal Tarifa { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Prodajna")]
        public Nullable<decimal> ProdajnaCijena { get; set; }
        [Browsable(false)]
        public Nullable<bool> Flag { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Kalo { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Nabavna")]
        public Nullable<decimal> NabavnaCijena { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Veleprodajna")]
        public Nullable<decimal> VeleprodajnaCijena { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Zalihe { get; set; }
 }
```

My question is how can I get the Artikl item based on property "Sifra". I have no idea how to call this method...

```
private void txtSifra_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var artikl = _UnitOfWork.Artikl.Find(???);
     txtNaziv.Text = artikl.Naziv;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) to satisfy `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate`. You can get the item based on property "Sifra" by doing this:

```
var artikl = _UnitOfWork.Artikl.Find(q => q.Sifra == "some int value").FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh. Sorry, but in that case, I suggest you use FirstOrDefault(), so it won't cause some crashes. Using First() when your Find() didn't return anything would lead to a crash.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers already explained how to use expression but I want to mention one thing that is often overlooked when using so-called repository pattern:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
}
```

This returns `IEnumerable<TEntity>` and because of that this:

```
var result = _UnitOfWork.Artikl.Find(c => c.Sifra == 1).FirstOrDefault()
```

Will **not** execute whole query in database. The database query will look (roughly) like this:

```
select * from Artikl where Sifra = 1 -- < not efficient
```

and not like this:

```
select top 1 * from Artikl where Sifra = 1 -- < efficient
```

To fix this issue you have to either return `IQueryable`:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
}
```

Or make separate method for every query you are going to make:

```
public TEntity FindFirst(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: why is "select * from Artikl where Sifra = 1" not efficient? I don't understand are you trying to point out?

Comment: @ChenChi, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet - this is to do with greedy loading too many records from the DB into memory.

Comment: @ChenChi I try to point out that "select **top 1** from Artikl where Sifra = 1" is more efficient than just "select * from Artikl where Sifra = 1". And if you return IEnumerable and later use FirstOrDefault - the latter query is executed. Worst part is that it will most likely go unnoticed, until the point where you will make a lot of queries or when your table becomes large (like at the point when you publish your code from development to production).

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` is like so, just pass in a lambda expression (pseudo-code):

```
var result = context.set.Find(x => x.Property == value);
```

So in your case:

```
var artiklList = _UnitOfWork.Artikl.Find(x => x.Sifra == 1);
var artikl = artiklList.FirstOrDefault();
```

Don't forget to return `.FirstOrDefault()` as the `Find` result will be an `IEnumerable<T>`.