# Entity Framework Core Postgres ILike function

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity

```
context.Company.Where(i => EF.Functions.ILike(i.Name, "xxx%")).FirstOrDefault()
```

I just need to use `ILike` in EF Core. But this function is Postgres specific.
If some day the database change to Sql Server. All the code like this need to be updated.

Any ways to avoid this issue?

Comment: why cant you use normal linq syntax ?

Comment: i need use ILike

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be database agnostic:

`context.Counties.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower())).ToList();`

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043524