# How to make EF.Functions.Like case-insensitive?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using the EF Core 3.1 + MySQL, and using this method for querying:

```
IQueryable<ApplicationUser> customers = from u in _context.Users where (u.Customer != null && u.IsActive) select u;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
customers = customers.Where(s => s.Email.Contains(searchString));
}
```

And I upgrade to using EF.Function.Like for better performance:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
customers = customers.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.Email, $"%{searchString}%"));
}
```

But it is case-sensitive, how to make it case-insensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionsextensions.like?view=efcore-5.0):

> Note that if this function is translated into SQL, then the semantics of the comparison will depend on the database configuration. In particular, it may be either case-sensitive or case-insensitive. If this function is evaluated on the client, then it will always use a case-insensitive comparison.

Therefore, it's not the function that is case-sensitive, but your database/column collation settings. You can use the [Collate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldbfunctionsextensions.collate?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalDbFunctionsExtensions_Collate__1_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbFunctions___0_System_String_) function to specify a different, case-insensitive collation. More on [MySQL collations](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-collation).

Comment: Funny we found the exact same quote. I was a little slow in finishing, though. I'll leave my answer since it's a little different from yours.

Comment: Thank you, I had change my mind, As your suggestion, I change my DB to make it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionsextensions.like?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbFunctionsExtensions_Like_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbFunctions_System_String_System_String_System_String_):

> Note that if this function is translated into SQL, then the semantics of the comparison will depend on the database configuration. In particular, it may be either case-sensitive or case-insensitive. If this function is evaluated on the client, then it will always use a case-insensitive comparison.

So, it depends on your server.

As a workaround you can make the argument uppercase.

```cs
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    customers = customers.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.Email.ToUpper(), $"%{searchString.ToUpper()}%"));
}
```

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions) there ought to be a function mapping to `UPPER` so you get the right SQL.

Comment: hiahia, Thank you very much.

Comment: Watch out for performance degradation when using this particular workaround though. See comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043524/4458009

Answer (score 0):

For postgres use `EF.Functions.ILike`:

```
customers = customers.Where(x => EF.Functions.ILike(x.Email, $"%{searchString}%"));
```

This will be translated to this query:

```
SELECT c."Email"
FROM yourSchema."Customers" AS c
WHERE c."Email" ILIKE @__Format_1 ESCAPE ''
```

Whereas toLower (or toUpper) gets called explicitly:

```
SELECT c."Email"
FROM yourSchema."Customers" AS c
WHERE lower(c."Email") LIKE @__ToLower_0_rewritten ESCAPE '\'
```

[Here](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/misc/collations-and-case-sensitivity.html#ilike) is the documentation from npgsql for further reading.