# Expression.Like alternative for filtering based on text in c#

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, expression, asp.net-core-3.1

We don't have some kind of Expression.Like in c#. So as an alternative, I am doing below work:

```
private static readonly MethodInfo StringContains = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
```

and then using it with expression like:

```
var contExpressions = new List<Expression>();
var equals = nonNullValues.Select(value =>
                               (Expression) Expression.Call(left, StringContains, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string)))).ToList();
                           contExpressions.AddRange(equals);
```

But this comparision is being case sensitive. I want the expression to ignore case.

The as an alternative, I tried using the indexof method as below:

```
private static readonly MethodInfo StringContainsIgnoreCase = typeof(string).GetMethod("IndexOf", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) });
```

and used with Expression as:

```
var equals = nonNullValues.Select(value =>
                            Expression.NotEqual(Expression.Call(left, StringContainsIgnoreCase, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string)), Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)), Expression.Constant(-1))).ToList();
                        contExpressions.AddRange(equals);
```

And then tried to make the final expression as:

```
var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(contExpressions.Count == 1 ? contExpressions[0] : contExpressions.Aggregate(Expression.Or), parameter);
```

This works for some cases but for other it throws exception as:

> LINQ could not be translated. could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Can anyone help me where I am going wrong and how can I perform a case-insensitive contains check using Expression?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277868/entity-framework-core-contains-is-case-sensitive-or-case-insensitive) help?

Comment: Why not just use: sSomeString.ToLower() on everything to ignore case?

Comment: @JesseChunn Is that really possible while generating Expression, Expression.NotEqual will expect Expressions and thus not possible to call string methods on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working as below:

```
private static readonly MethodInfo StringContainsIgnoreCase =typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like), new[] { Expression.Property(null, typeof(EF).GetProperty(nameof(EF.Functions)) ??throw new InvalidOperationException()).Type, typeof(string), typeof(string)
    });
```

and then use below to make Expression:

```
var equals = nonNullValues.Select(value =>
                        Expression.Call(null, StringContainsIgnoreCase, Expression.Property(null, typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Functions)), left, Expression.Constant($"%{value}%", typeof(string)))).ToList();
                    contExpressions.AddRange(equals);
```

This works like charm when you need to have a Expression to perform a string case insensitive contains work.