# Wrong case sensitivity using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, model-view-controller

Please help with the following result. I am using linq to perform a query. I know the String.Equals(string) is case sensitive, and I have tested it. However, when I am applying String.Equals functions in the linq statement below, the result is case insensitive. And I can not find what went wrong.

In the result below, I am searching for "qiao", however, "Qiao" was returned as a valid result. And it is not expected. Please help.

[image: Code and debugging results]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277868/entity-framework-core-contains-is-case-sensitive-or-case-insensitive)

Comment: If it is the database and i am doing code first, what i can do from the c# side to make the db case sensitive?

Comment: Here's the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity

Comment: Does the Contact class in c# have a custom Equal method?

Comment: You can do the case insensitive check on the DB then do a case sensitive check on the client side like `query.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Name == "qiao")`

Answer (score 0):

for case-sensitive result you can try `==` operator instead of `.Equals()` method -

```
var query = from c in db.Contacts where c.Name == "qiao" select c;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ToUpperCase()` or `ToLowerCase` to solve case sensitivity problem.
Example-

```
var query = from c in db.Contacts where c.Name.ToUpperCase().Equals("QIAO")
select c;
```

Comment: You have added opposite to the question answer.