# Postgres EFCore generating a case insensitive query which uses ILIKE ANY

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

So I'm using EntityFramework Core with Npgsql provider in my project.

I have the following query, which uses `Array.Contains`.

```
var symbols = new[] { "AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT" };
var instruments = dbContext.Instruments.Where(t => symbols.Contains(t.Symbol)).ToList();
```

Which produces sql like:

```
select [columns] from instruments where symbol = ANY(ARRAY["AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT"])
```

As you can see, it translates the `Array.Contains` into an `ANY` clause, which is case sensitive.

Instead, I want a case insensitive query to be generated using `ILIKE ANY`. Something like the following:

```
select [columns] from instruments where symbol ILIKE ANY(ARRAY["AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT"])
```

Is this possible to do with Npgsql?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework core - Contains is case sensitive or case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277868/entity-framework-core-contains-is-case-sensitive-or-case-insensitive). (The [2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043524/5298879))

Comment: @Zegarek, that works for non-array string comparison. I wish there was an overload for `EF.Functions.ILike`, which worked for string collections.

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see, it translates the Array.Contains into an ANY clause, which is case sensitive.

ANY isn't case-sensitive or sensitive; the case sensitivity is determined by the column being compared here (`symbol`). Give the [EF docs on collations and case sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity) a good read and consider switching symbol to a case-insensitive collation.

Comment: If we leave the collation bit aside for a while, is there any way to write a linq query which translates into an sql query that uses `ILIKE ANY`?

Comment: Yes: https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/blob/main/test/EFCore.PG.FunctionalTests/Query/ArrayArrayQueryTest.cs#L660