# How does LINQ work with Sitecore item.GetChildren()?

Tags: c#, linq, sitecore, sitecore8

Suppose, we have a line of code

```
item.GetChildren().Where(i => i.Name == "something");
```

where item is of type Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.

How does it work?

1) after .GetChildren() call a query to database gets invoked, results returned, and then .Where(i => i.Name == "something") happens on client side

or

2) .Where(i => i.Name == "something") gets appended to the database query and only after that the database query gets invoked and results returned?

or both options aren't correct?

Comment: What is the type that is returned by `GetChildren`?

Comment: That depends on what `GetChildren()` is.

Comment: The [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/developing/developing%20with%20sitecore/search%20and%20item%20buckets/linq%20to%20sitecore) has a good explanation. To be clear I am not suggesting that asking questions about documented features is inappropriate but in this case the documentation seems very clear and it _seems_ unlikely that a better answer will be provided here.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet

Comment: @JasonBoyd documentation is about performing LINQ on IQueryable<T> returned by SearchContext. I ask about performing LINQ on item.GetChildren(), which returns ChildList. And these work differently, I believe.

Comment: @Arran Sitecore.Collections.ChildList : IEnumerable<Item>, ICollection, IEnumerable

Comment: I see. Perhaps you can use Fiddler to inspect the response returned from SiteCore to see if it does or does not contain items that you expect to be filtered out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetChildren` call will return all Children of the item and then the Linq statement will filter the item collection based on your predicate. It is not done at a database query level, but it is done on the web server (I assume this is what you mean when you say client side, and not browser side).

To break it down, `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.GetChildren()` calls  `Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetChildren()` which is the default item provider set via config/DI. This makes a query to the database. This returns `Sitecore.Collections.ChildList` which as you point out inherits from `IReadOnlyList<Item>, IReadOnlyCollection<Item>, IEnumerable<Item>, IEnumerable, ICollection`.

The Linq statement then filters the items, using the `Where` extension method. This is for all practical reasons similar to using a foreach loop, adding only the items which match your predicate and then returning that list.

Depending on what you are doing, how many items you have, if you have followed best practice of not having more than 100 child items per node then it shouldn't cause any significant performance issues.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the answer I was waiting for.
I guess, the only way to build database query using LINQ statements in Sitecore is ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(item).CreateSearchContext().GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(...)?

Comment: Yes, that's the best and most performant way usually. There's a couple bits to hook up for the predicate builder but suggest looking at [this](http://www.bekagool.com/news-and-insights/sitecore-7-search-a-quickstart-guide) or [this](http://www.mattburkedev.com/sitecore-7-contentsearch-tips/) as a starting point