# Filtering with EF Core 2.1 inheritance

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I'm trying to find a way to filter my results in EF Core 2.1, when using inherited objects.

I've got a base model and *several* inherited classes (but I've just included one):

```
public class Like {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public LikeType LikeType { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentLike : Like {
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Document))]
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Document Document { get; set; }
}
```

`LikeType` is an enum which is defined as the discriminator in the dbcontext. Every `Document` has a boolean property `.IsCurrent`.

To get all items from the database, I'm using a query like:

```
IQueryable<Like> query = _context.Set<Like>()
    .Include(x => x.Owner)
    .Include(x => (x as DocumentLike).Document.DocumentType)
    .Include(x => (x as ProductLike).Product)
    .Include(x => (x as TrainingLike).Training)
```

This works beautifully, and returns all objects with the included sub-objects without any error. What I'm trying to do, is to get all items from the database for which the linked document has `.IsCurrent == true`. I've tried adding the following to the query above, but both result in an exception:

```
.Where(x => (x as DocumentLike).Document.IsCurrent == true)
```

And:

```
.Where(x => x.LikeType == LikeType.Document ? (x as DocumentLike).Document.IsCurrent == true : true)
```

The exception, which is thrown when I'm executing the query:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    lambda_method(Closure , TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<Like, ApplicationUser>, Organisation>, Training>, Product>, Platform>, NewsItem>, Event>, Document>, DocumentType>, Course>, CourseType>, ApplicationUser> )
    System.Linq.Utilities+<>c__DisplayClass1_0<TSource>.<CombinePredicates>b__0(TSource x)
    System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<TSource, TResult>.MoveNext()
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities<TOut, TIn>(IEnumerable<TOut> results, QueryContext queryContext, IList<EntityTrackingInfo> entityTrackingInfos, IList<Func<TIn, object>> entityAccessors)+MoveNext()
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider+ExceptionInterceptor<T>+EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
    System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
```

Is there a way to do this?

**UPDATE:**
To clarify: I'm looking to get a single query that returns all `Like`-objects from the database, regardless of their (sub)types. In case the subtype is `DocumentLike`, I only want the objects that are linked to a document that has `.IsCurrent == true`.

Comment: If you only want to load one type, don't add all those includes. Use `_context.Set<Like>().OfType<DocumentLike>()` to load only instances of this type BUT FIRST read about [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval). If EF Core doesn't support that operator it could load everything in memory and then try to filter the data. Make sure you add `.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));` in your configuration to prevent this

Comment: The `UPDATE` essentially asks how to filter children of a specific type

Comment: Well, it actually asks how to filter objects based on a property that's only available in an inherited class.

Comment: The condition you should be `x is not DocumentLike or it is and Document.IsCurrent is true`. You could try `.Where(x => !(x is DocumentLike) || ((DocumentLike)x).Document.IsCurrent == true)`. You don't need the comparison to `true` if `IsCurrent` isn't nullable. I haven't tried this though and I'd use the config warning anyway to ensure EF doesn't try to evaluate this on the client side

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick was to edit the predicate a bit, like this:

`.Where(x => !(x is DocumentLike) || ((DocumentLike)x).Document.IsCurrent == true)`

Thanks to [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, `as` not working, but instead casting can do it. This is strange

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with a multi-layer hierarchy of classes where using `.OfType<>()` was causing a "premature" (in my opinion) trip to the database to fetch **all** of the data so it could do the filtering in memory, which is undesirable!

This illustrates my hierarchy:

```
public abstract class BaseSetting {}
public abstract class AccountSetting : BaseSetting {}
public abstract class UserSetting : BaseSetting {}

public class AccountSettingA : AccountSetting {}
public class AccountSettingB : AccountSetting {}
public class UserSettingA : UserSetting {}
public class UserSettingB : UserSetting {}
```

And this is the set up for the `DbContext`:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
  public virtual DbSet<BaseSetting> Settings { get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
  {
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<BaseSetting>(e =>
    {
        e.ToTable("Settings");
        e.HasDiscriminator<string>("Type");
    });
  }
}
```

Then I would try and get all the settings for a single account like this:

```
AccountSetting[] settings = context.Settings
    .OfType<AccountSetting>()
    .Where(s => s.Account.Id == accountId)
    .ToArray();
```

This results in a SQL query something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Settings] AS [s0]
WHERE [s0].[Type] IN (N'AccountSettingA',N'AccountSettingB',N'UserSettingA',N'UserSettingB')
```

just before is throws a `NullReferenceException` in the `.Where(s => s.Account.Id == accountId)` bit of the query because `Account` is null. This could probably be "fixed" by adding a `.Include(...)` to the query to pull the `Account` through too, but that will just add to the excessive amount of data we're getting from the database. (It should be noted that if you configure the context to throw errors when trying to evaluate on the client as per @PanagiotisKanavos's comment on the original question, then you will get a `QueryClientEvaluationWarning` here instead).

The solution (at least for me) was to add this to the `OnModelCreating` method in my `DbContext`:

```
typeof(BaseSetting).Assembly.GetTypes()
  .Where(t => t != typeof(BaseSetting) && typeof(BaseSetting).IsAssignableFrom(t))
  .Each(s => builder.Entity(s).HasBaseType(s.BaseType));
```

This will go through all my different settings classes (that inherit from `BaseSetting`) and tell Entity Framework that their base type is their `Type.BaseType`. I would have thought that EF could work this out on it's own, but after doing this I get SQL like this (and no `QueryClientEvaluationWarning` exceptions!):

```
SELECT *
FROM [Settings] as [a]
INNER JOIN [Accounts] AS [a.Account] ON [a].[AccountId] = [a.Account].[Id]
WHERE ([a].[Type] IN (N'AccountSettingA',N'AccountSettingB',N'UserSettingA',N'UserSettingB')
AND ([a.Account].[Id] = @__accountId)
```

Which obviously only returns the **account** settings for the account I'm interested in, rather than **all** the account settings **and all of the user settings** like it was before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Enumerable.OfType to filter types. For more information you can have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-2.1

And for your case, you can simply filter your result by

```
var documentLikes = query.OfType<DocumentLike>();
```

Comment: Using `Enumerable.OfType` would have to load everything from the database in order to filter the results in memory. Unfortunately, EF Core often loads data in memory if it can't generate a corresponding SQL statement

Comment: Are you sure about this? Because I can see there is IQueryable.OfType method as well which returns IQuerayable back. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: that's *IQueryable* while you posted about *IEnumerable*.

Comment: IQueryable is implementing IEnumerable; so I dont see your point of data being loaded in memory before OfType can do the required filtering. Data will be loaded in memory only when ToList() or ToArray() is called on top of an IEnumerable or IQueryable or if you are enumerating the list explicitly.

Comment: no, that's not how either of them works. The interfaces *don't* implement any of those methods. Those are extension methods. In IEnumerable's case, they work on the in-memory objects themselves. In IQueryable, they are just specifications that the *provider* will convert to whatever it wants. This is a well known pitfall since the very first days of LINQ anyway. You'll find a nice explanation [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet)

Comment: BTW that's explained in the very links you posted - the `OfType` link points to the `OfType` method of the [Queryable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable?view=netframework-4.7.2) static class

Comment: And regardless, it does not do what I need. I'm looking for a way to return all subtypes of `Like`, but in the case it's a `DocumentLike` I only want the likes that are linked to a document that has `.IsCurrent == true`.