# How to list all items when using inheritance?

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

I'm trying to work with inheritance. I have three models

```
class Animal {string name;}
class Cat : Animal {int meowPerHour}
class Dog : Animal {bool mixedBreed}
```

Ef core has created a Discriminator column and I can list Cats or Dogs seperately and I can create new items. 
The problem is that I'd like to list both all animals with their respective unique properties. E.g. if the row is a Cat, print meowPerHour. But the mewPerHour is not a property or method in the Animal Class. I'm using the code below to print all animals.

```
public IList<Animal> Aniamls { get;set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
   Animals = await _context.Animal.ToListAsync();
}
```

How may I solve this?

Comment: The classes are retrieved correctly, but since you access the base class you only see the base (shared) properties. You need to check every single item for its type and then access its properties (i.e. when printing them using a switch statement). When you deserialize the data to JSON it should still work, since Json will serialize the real class not the base type passed. If your only goal is to retrieve all of a type for some looping you can do `.OfType<Dog>()` to get all dogs from that retrieved list

Comment: Is it an answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044407/filtering-with-ef-core-2-1-inheritance?

Comment: @OxQ Yes. Thank you.

Comment: @Alex, you are welcome) can you upvote my comment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following approach but be careful about this approach is eagerly loading all Animals and may not be suits best for all your cases.

```
public IEnumerable<IAnimal> GetAllAnimals()
{
  List<IAnimal> allAnimals = GetAllEntriesByEntityInterface<IAnimal>();
  return allAnimals;
}
```

Method for combining all entitties in one list

```
private List<T> GetAllEntries<T>() where T : class
{
  List<IQueryable<T>> sets = typeof(T).IsInterface ? GetAllSetsByInterface<T>() : GetAllSetsByBaseClass<T>();

  List<T> allEntries = new List<T>();
  foreach (var item in sets)
  {
    allEntries.AddRange(item.ToList());
  }

  return allEntries;
}
```

Here we are gettings all Sets of entities implementing generic class of T. This method may be useful if you need to work with Interfaces.

```
private List<IQueryable<T>> GetAllSetsByInterface<T>() where T : class
{
  var types = context.Model.GetEntityTypes().Select(t => t.ClrType).ToList().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(T))).ToList();
  var sets = types.Select(type =>
                      context.GetType()
                        .GetMethod("Set")
                        .MakeGenericMethod(type)
                        .Invoke(context, null)
                        as IQueryable<T>
                      ).ToList();
  return sets;
}
```

And method for fetching all Sets of entities derived from generic class of T

```
private List<IQueryable<T>> GetAllSetsByBaseClass<T>() where T : class
{
  var types = context.Model.GetEntityTypes().Select(t => t.ClrType).Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))).ToList();
  var sets = types.Select(type =>
                      context.GetType()
                        .GetMethod("Set")
                        .MakeGenericMethod(type)
                        .Invoke(context, null)
                        as IQueryable<T>
                      ).ToList();
  return sets;
```

}