# EF Core dynamic filter

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, ef-core-2.1

I've been working in a Dynamic filter class for EF Core queries using Expression trees, everything looks good, filter is working, I can pass a filter collection and it works, but when I look at the SQL sentence, it is querying the whole table and applying the filter on the resulting collection, here is my class...

```
   public static class QueryExpressionBuilder
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo ContainsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
    private static readonly MethodInfo StartsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
    private static readonly MethodInfo EndsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });

    #region DynamicWhere

    /// <summary>Where expression generator.</summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="filters">The filters.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(IList<Filter> filters)
    {
        if (filters.Count == 0)
            return null;

        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
        Expression exp = null;

        if (filters.Count == 1)
            exp = GetExpression(param, filters[0]);
        else if (filters.Count == 2)
            exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]);
        else
        {
            while (filters.Count > 0)
            {
                var f1 = filters[0];
                var f2 = filters[1];

                if (exp == null)
                    exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]);
                else
                    exp = Expression.AndAlso(exp, GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]));

                filters.Remove(f1);
                filters.Remove(f2);

                if (filters.Count == 1)
                {
                    exp = Expression.AndAlso(exp, GetExpression(param, filters[0]));
                    filters.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }
        }

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, param);
    }

    /// <summary>Comparision operator expression generator.</summary>
    /// <param name="param">The parameter.</param>
    /// <param name="filter">The filter.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static Expression GetExpression(ParameterExpression param, Filter filter)
    {
        MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.PropertyName);
        var type = member.Type;
        ConstantExpression constant;
        switch (type.Name)
        {
            case "Int32":
                constant = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToInt32(filter.Value));
                break;
            case "String":
            default:
                constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);
                break;
        }

        // ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);

        switch (filter.Operation)
        {
            case Op.Equals:
                return Expression.Equal(member, constant);

            case Op.GreaterThan:
                return Expression.GreaterThan(member, constant);

            case Op.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, constant);

            case Op.LessThan:
                return Expression.LessThan(member, constant);

            case Op.LessThanOrEqual:
                return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member, constant);

            case Op.Contains:
                return Expression.Call(member, ContainsMethod, constant);

            case Op.StartsWith:
                return Expression.Call(member, StartsWithMethod, constant);

            case Op.EndsWith:
                return Expression.Call(member, EndsWithMethod, constant);
        }

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>And logic connector expression generator.</summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="param">The parameter.</param>
    /// <param name="filter1">The filter1.</param>
    /// <param name="filter2">The filter2.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static BinaryExpression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, Filter filter1, Filter filter2)
    {
        var bin1 = GetExpression(param, filter1);
        var bin2 = GetExpression(param, filter2);

        return Expression.AndAlso(bin1, bin2);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

}

To call this class I do something like this :

```
var whereDeleg = QueryExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<Tax>(filters).Compile();
var myList = _dbContext.MyEntity.Where(whereDeleg).ToList();
```

The filters parameter i'm passing is a collection of this class :

```
public class Filter
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public Op Operation { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the generated sql and what is the expected?

Comment: why do I have a feeling that it is about [IQueryable<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) and [IEnumerable<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)? If so, please refer to [IQueryable<T> vs IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2876655/2417602).

Comment: you can use Gridify library. https://github.com/alirezanet/gridify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is not the class, but the way you use it:

```
var whereDeleg = QueryExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<Tax>(filters).Compile();
var myList = _dbContext.MyEntity.Where(whereDeleg).ToList();
```

You are taking `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` from your method, but then the `Complie()` call converts it to `Func<T, bool>`. So although `_dbContext.MyEntity` is `IQueryable<T>`, there is no `IQueryable<T>` extension method `Where` taking `Func<T, bool>` (all they take `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`). But since `IQueryable<T>` inherits (hence is a) `IEnumerable<T>`, the compiler finds and uses the `Where` extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` (defined in `Enumerable` class).

This makes the `Where` (and all following methods if any) to execute client side after executing and materializing the query before `Where` (in your case - the whole table).

The difference between `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` is covered by [Returning IEnumerable<T> vs. IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet/2876655#2876655). All you need is to make sure you always call `IQueryable<T>` extension methods instead of the `IEnumerable<T>` methods with the same name and similarly *looking* arguments by using `Expression<Func<...>>` instead of `Func<...>`.

With all that being said, you should use your method result directly without calling `Compile`:

```
var predicate = QueryExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<Tax>(filters);
var myList = _dbContext.MyEntity.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

or just

```
var myList = _dbContext.MyEntity.Where(QueryExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<Tax>(filters)).ToList();
```

Or even better, add the following custom extension method to the `QueryExpressionBuilder` class:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IList<Filter> filters)
{
    var predicate = GetExpression<T>(filters);
    return predicate != null ? source.Where(predicate) : source;
}
```

to be able to use simply (and minimize the chance of making mistakes):

```
var myList = _dbContext.MyEntity.Where(filters).ToList();
```

---

Side note: The main expression builder method implementation is overcomplicated and also destroys the passed input `filters` list. It can be simplified as follows (which doesn't have the aforementioned defect):

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(IEnumerable<Filter> filters)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
    var body = filters
        .Select(filter => GetExpression(param, filter))
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        .Aggregate(Expression.AndAlso);
    return body != null ? Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated to include more data types:

```
private static Expression GetExpression(ParameterExpression param, Filter filter)
{
    // Defaults
    FilterOperation filterOp = FilterOperation.Equals;
    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);

    MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.PropertyName);
    var type = member.Type;

    switch (type.FullName)
    {
        case "System.Guid":
            Guid outGuid;
            if (Utilities.IsGuid(filter.Value.ToString(), out outGuid))
                constant = Expression.Constant(outGuid);
            break;
        case "System.DateTime":
            if (Utilities.IsDate(filter.Value.ToString()))
                constant = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToDateTime(filter.Value));
            break;
        case "System.Single":
            if (Utilities.IsNumber(filter.Value.ToString()))
                constant = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToSingle(filter.Value));
            break;
        case "System.Int16":
            if (Utilities.IsNumber(filter.Value.ToString()))
                constant = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToInt16(filter.Value));
            break;
        case "System.Int32":
            if (Utilities.IsNumber(filter.Value.ToString()))
                constant = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToInt32(filter.Value));
            break;
        case "System.Double":
            if (Utilities.IsNumber(filter.Value.ToString()))
                constant = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToDouble(filter.Value));
            break;
        case "System.Decimal":
            if (Utilities.IsNumber(filter.Value.ToString()))
                constant = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToDecimal(filter.Value));
            break;
        case "System.Boolean":
            if (Utilities.isBoolean(filter.Value.ToString().ToLower()))
            {
                constant = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToBoolean(filter.Value));
                filterOp = FilterOperation.BooleanEquals;
            }
            break;
        case "System.String":
            constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);
            filterOp = FilterOperation.Contains;
            break;
    }

    switch (filterOp)
    {
        case FilterOperation.Equals:
            return Expression.Equal(member, constant);

        case FilterOperation.BooleanEquals:
            var valueExpression = Expression.Convert(constant, typeof(bool));
            return Expression.Equal(member, valueExpression);

        case FilterOperation.GreaterThan:
            return Expression.GreaterThan(member, constant);

        case FilterOperation.GreaterThanOrEqual:
            return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, constant);

        case FilterOperation.LessThan:
            return Expression.LessThan(member, constant);

        case FilterOperation.LessThanOrEqual:
            return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member, constant);

        case FilterOperation.Contains:
            return Expression.Call(member, ContainsMethod, constant);

        case FilterOperation.StartsWith:
            return Expression.Call(member, StartsWithMethod, constant);

        case FilterOperation.EndsWith:
            return Expression.Call(member, EndsWithMethod, constant);
    }

    return null;
}

    public enum FilterOperation
    {
        Equals,
        BooleanEquals,
        GreaterThan,
        GreaterThanOrEqual,
        LessThan,
        LessThanOrEqual,
        Contains,
        StartsWith,
        EndsWith
    }
```

Validation is optional but if you need it:

```
public static bool IsDate(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) return false;

    try
    {
        string strDate = obj.ToString();

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strDate);
        if (dt != DateTime.MinValue && dt != DateTime.MaxValue)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public static bool IsNumber(string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return false;

    bool isNum;
    double retNum;
    isNum = Double.TryParse(str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out retNum);
    return isNum;

}
public static bool IsGuid(string str, out Guid theGuid)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        theGuid = Guid.Empty;
        return false;
    }

    return Guid.TryParse(str, out theGuid);
}
public static bool isBoolean(string str)
{
    if (bool.TryParse(str, out _))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```