# How to make a dynamic Include filter in EF core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I was able to create a dynamic filter from a string expression and passed it to the **Where** function of the main IQueryable object, which takes an **Expression<Func<T, bool>>** parameter. My goal is to apply the same dynamic filtering functionality to child/related entities using the **Include** function. However, the **Include** function takes a **Func<T, bool>** instead of an Expression tree. How do I compose the Func<T, bool> dynamically without hard-coding the child entity's properties?

[image]

Comment: Hi @JeonsoftFaceBundy, it is better to post the relates code, instead of post a screenshot about the code block. And can you share the definition about the `Expression<Func<Verder, bool>>`, from your code it looks that it already works well on the parent filter, right? Besides, here are some similar threads, you could refer them: [EF Core dynamic filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53773921/) and [How to construct a dynamic where filter in EF.Core to handle equals, LIKE, gt, lt, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306955/).

Comment: @ZhiLv I just realized that I need to convert the child collection to an IQueryable: `e.Locations` to `e.Locations.AsQueryable()` so it enables me to pass an Expression instead of a Func.