# IQueryable.Concat, IEnumerable.Concat, Linq GroupBy then OrderBy within each group

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, ienumerable, iqueryable

What I'm doing so far is this:

Entities:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateOn { get; set; }
}

public class Request : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public Approval Approval { get; set; }
}

public class Approval // Value object
{
    public bool? IsApproved { get; set; }
}
```

Repo:

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<Request>> GetAllAsync()
{
    IQueryable<Request> requests = await _dbContext.Requests.ToListAsync();
    IQueryable<Request> pending = requests.Where(r => r.Approval.IsApproved == null).OrderBy(r => r.CreateOn);
    IQueryable<Request> processed = requests.Where(r => r.Approval.IsApproved != null).OrderByDescending(r => r.CreateOn);

    return pending.Concat(processed).ToListAsync();
}
```

The problem I have is when I iterate through the result of `GetAllAsync` and `IsApproved` **has** a value, `Approval` is set to `null`. If I only return `requests` without concatenating, it works as expected (the object is created, but the values within are `null`).

I suspect the problem is with concatenating two queries. How can I rewrite what I have in a single query?

The requests should be grouped by processed and not processed (`IsApproved == null` and `IsApproved != null`), then ordered by `CreatedOn` in different orders.

Would also greatly appreciate if someone can explain to me why after concatenating, `Approval` is set to `null` if `IsApproved` has a value. Also, when I wait enough (~5s), while debugging through each iteration, it works as expected. Maybe there's a late reference that doesn't `await` for some process to finish?

While writing this post, I did some testing. If I change `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` it works as expected. After some more digging, I found this:

> Queryable.Concat(IQueryable, IEnumerable) Method
>
> Enumerable.Concat(IEnumerable, IEnumerable) Method

So I assume if I pass an `IQueryable`, instead of `IEnumerable`, to `Queryable.Concat()`, then I lose some references? I'm so confused.

Comment: Shouldn't `requests` be of type `IList<Request>`? Then `pending` and `processed` would be `IEnumerable<Request>` and the last line would be `ToList()` instead of `ToListAsync()`.

Comment: Have you tried to make your `pending` and `processed` into a List using `.ToList()` and then doing `pending.Concat(processed).ToList`, to make sure there is nothing else going on

Comment: Wouldn't that have an impact on performance? Somewhere else in the code I'm doing another `.Where(...)` so it would be something like `Where(...).ToList().Where(...)`.

Comment: As per this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2876655/2949081), I want to do LINQ-to-SQL.