# Performance Impact of Using DefaultIfEmpty on Linq Join

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have been playing around with [left joins in linq](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9#leftouterjoin) and found that it is necessary to use `DefaultIfEmpty()` in order to change the join from an `inner` to a `left`.

Looking at the return type of `DefaultIfEmpty()`, I became concerned from a performance perspective as I see that it's returning an [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=netframework-4.7.2), which we know [caches the data locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet). In my scenario, I am further processing the data post left joining and would ideally like to preserve the type as `IQueryable` instead, however when I deployed the solution as is to my dev environment, I was surprised to see a counter-intuitive/minimal performance impact.

Why is it that the `DefaultIfEmpty()` does not seem to have a significant performance impact, or am I not understanding the situation properly?

**Edit:** 
Below is my code:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ther are both `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` overloads of `DefaultIfEmpty()`. `IEnumerable` version is used on inmemory Linq and `IQueryable` version with expressions for example with EF.

If you began with a `Queryable` and end up with a `IEnumerable` you consume your Queryable somwhere along the line

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This example looked awesome so I tried to copy it but surprisingly this breaks something with postgres and throw the exceptaion: `InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure., at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, TResult> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, ExecutionResult<TResult>> verifySucceeded) in NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.cs, line 37`

Comment: The select many? Yeah its a nifty way of doing left joins.  It works fine with SQL and EF