# How to query with entity and fitlering and pagedlist with one milion rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ienumerable, pagedlist

I want To query 1 million rows with entity framework and then paging them. I use pagedlist.mvc library and it is not problem for first page because I used `.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)` in My code and it is not necessary to load all of my data.

```
 var allrows = db.works.Where(x => x.Status == 100).OrderByDescending(x => x.ID_Work).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

but when I add filtering and paging action, First I should load All rows and then filter them and after that use `.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)`.

```
var allrows = db.works.Where(x => x.Status == 100);
     if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Code_Work))
      {
       allrows= allrows.Where(x => x.Code_Work.Contains(Code_Work));
       ViewBag.CurrentCode_Work = Code_Work;
      }
var pagedrows = allrows.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID_Work).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

How Can I handle this challenge. I think it could be problem and reduce performance. I don't want to load all of my rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read difference between [IEnumerable and IQueryable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet)

**In your case you need to first make the filter query using  IQueryable**

```
IQueryable<works> worksDetails = db.works.Where(x => x.Status == 100)
              .OrderByDescending(x => x.ID_Work); // just creates the sql query to filter records
```

**Finally hit the database to get records using PagedList**

```
var pagedrows = worksDetails.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize); 
                                // hits the database and executes the sql query to filter records
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok and then when we use IQueryable  it doesn't load data ? it's good.

Comment: @AliSHelcid , yes correct, its's good because it first creates the query and then runs it in the database. So only filtered records are retrieved from database. But in the case of  `IEnumerable` all 1 million rows is retrieved from database and then it filters the data, So there is performance loss.