# Can IQueryable be used for in-memory collections?

Tags: c#

Most of the blogs suggest to use `IEnumerable` for in-memory collections. Are there any advantages? Can I use `IQueryable` for in-memory collections also?

Comment: Why would you want to use it for in-memory collections? You can convert any `IEnumerable` to `IQueryable` with `AsQueryable` but that only introduces unnecessary overhead since almost all method `IQueryable` also exists for `IEnumerable`

Comment: If there's a measurable difference, it'll be that IQueryable is slower - because it works in terms of expression trees which means some compilation is postponed until runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Check [IQueryable documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=net-5.0)

```
public interface IQueryable : System.Collections.IEnumerable
```

`IQueryable` implements `IEnumerable`, so you can do whatever you can with `IEnumerable` and more.

Check the differences here: [Returning IEnumerable<T> vs. IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet)

Basically:

- `IQueryable` -> Linq to Sql
- `IEnumerable` -> Linq to Objects

If it's not SQL or any other data source (not objects), then you have no reason to use `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an oversimplification, but IQueryable basically is a marker interface for APIs that translate the IQueryable calls to queries for a particular storage engine, such as a database.

Querying a `List<T>` or other collection with IQueryable extension methods is not going to turn that into database calls, because the storage isn't a database; it's in application memory and will be executed by the runtime.