# OrderBy with IEnumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ienumerable

I am using Entity Framework 5.0 and I have this `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I use `OrderBy` on an `IEnumerable` object:

```
 IEnumerable lstPerson<Person>
```

I found that I can use

```
 lstPerson = lstPerson.OrderBy("FirstName", SortDirection.Ascending);
```

But when I get the `lstPerson` from database, I must use

```
lstPerson.OrderBy(e => e.FirstName);
```

Why I can not use

```
 lstPerson.OrderBy("FirstName", SortDirection.Ascending)
```

with `IEnumerable` from database?

Comment: `IEnumerable lstPerson<Person>` - this does not look like something which will compile in C#.

Comment: And `.OrderBy("FirstName",SortDirection.Ascending)` does not look like something from BCL, but maybe I'm forgetting something. Either way you should not use methods based on `IEnumerable` when working with EF, only `IQueryable` ones.

Comment: *"Why I can not use..."*. Because you can't just make up methods that seem convenient. You can only call methods that actually exist.

Comment: Presumably `IEnumerable lstPerson<Person>` should be `IEnumerable<Person> lstPerson`.

Comment: Using `IEnumerable<T>` could be catastrophically bad for large data - that does things client side. To move things server side, you need to retain `IQueryable<T>`. For a string (member-name) based sort: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/233505/23354

Comment: Check this one too for IQueryable/IEnumerable differences: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2876655/3231884

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lstPerson.OrderBy(e => e.FirstName)` because there is an extension [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-6.0) that microsoft has written that works on an `IEnumerable` if you supply it a `predicate` ie *e => e.FirstName*.

You **cannot** use `lstPerson.OrderBy("FirstName", SortDirection.Ascending)` because there is **no** method that works on an `IEnumerable` if you supply it a `string` and a `SortDirection`.

There is a [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sort?view=netframework-4.8) called `GridView.Sort` that you might be familiar with, but that one only works on a `GridView` (if you provide it a `string` and a `SortDirection`). You arent working with a gridview here so it cant be used.

Comment: To be precise, that method works on an `IEnumerable<T>` rather than an `IEnumerable`, which would require a call to `Cast<T>` first.